# Algorithm for Determining Tic Tac Toe Game Over

Tags: algorithm, state, tic-tac-toe

I've written a game of tic-tac-toe in Java, and my current method of determining the end of the game accounts for the following possible scenarios for the game being over:

1. The board is full, and no winner has yet been declared: Game is a draw.
2. Cross has won.
3. Circle has won.

Unfortunately, to do so, it reads through a predefined set of these scenarios from a table. This isn't necessarily bad considering that there are only 9 spaces on a board, and thus the table is somewhat small, but is there a better algorithmic way of determining if the game is over? The determination of whether someone has won or not is the meat of the problem, since checking if 9 spaces are full is trivial.

The table method might be the solution, but if not, what is? Also, what if the board were not size `n=9`? What if it were a much larger board, say `n=16`, `n=25`, and so on, causing the number of consecutively placed items to win to be `x=4`, `x=5`, etc? A general algorithm to use for all `n = { 9, 16, 25, 36 ... }`?

Comment: I'm adding my 2 cents for all the answers: You always know you need at least a number of Xs or Os on the board for a win (in normal 3x3 board it's `3`). So you can track the counts of each, and only start checking for wins if they are higher.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You know a winning move can only happen after X or O has made their most recent move, so you can only search row/column with optional diag that are contained in that move to limit your search space when trying to determine a winning board.  Also since there are a fixed number of moves in a draw tic-tac-toe game once the last move is made if it wasn't a winning move it's by default a draw game.

This code is for an n by n board with n in a row to win (3x3 board requires 3 in a row, etc)

```js
public class TripleT {
    
    enum State{Blank, X, O};
    
    int n = 3;
    State[][] board = new State[n][n];
    int moveCount;
    
    void Move(int x, int y, State s){
        if(board[x][y] == State.Blank){
            board[x][y] = s;
        }
        moveCount++;
        
        //check end conditions
        
        //check col
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(board[x][i] != s)
                break;
            if(i == n-1){
                //report win for s
            }
        }
        
        //check row
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(board[i][y] != s)
                break;
            if(i == n-1){
                //report win for s
            }
        }
        
        //check diag
        if(x == y){
            //we're on a diagonal
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                if(board[i][i] != s)
                    break;
                if(i == n-1){
                    //report win for s
                }
            }
        }
            
        //check anti diag (thanks rampion)
        if(x + y == n - 1){
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                if(board[i][(n-1)-i] != s)
                    break;
                if(i == n-1){
                    //report win for s
                }
            }
        }

        //check draw
        if(moveCount == (Math.pow(n, 2) - 1)){
            //report draw
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent point.  Don't waste time searching the whole board when you know that only a small subset (1 row, 1 column, 2 diagonals on a 2d board) are relevant :)

Comment: You forgot to check the anti-diagonal.

Comment: I added code to check the anti diag, but I couldn't figure out a non-loop way to determine if the point was on the anti diag so I left that initial check out.

Comment: For a 3x3 board, x+y will always equal 2 on the anti-diagonal, will always be even in the center and corners of the board, and odd elsewhere.

Comment: @Hardwareguy: a game can we be won only after atleast four moves. So, you might want to check the winning thing only if moveCount>4

Comment: For the anti-diagonal, try x==2-y as your if condition.

Comment: @TimeToCodeTheRoad It is possible to win a game on the third move.

Comment: I don't understand draw check at the end, shouldn't it not subtract 1?

Comment: There are cases where a player wins in the last possible (9th) move. In that case both a winner and a draw will be reported...

Comment: In terms of time complexity, what is the problem to check after each move the whole board, instead of just part of it?? O(n) = O(n/2) ...

Comment: @Asad I'm probably missing something but how can the game be won in 3 moves if there are two players? o, x, o or vice versa?

Comment: @gratz I think it's because my solution allows a variable board size ('n' variable), so technically if n=2 the board can be won on the 3rd move.

Comment: I have recently coded Tic Tac Toe in Javascript (not Java). Win-state detection is performed by two functions; `lookForWinner(row, col)` (10 lines) and `scanCells(a, val)` (4 lines). That's 14 lines total including function wrappers! Moreover, these functions not only detect a win state but also apply a highlighting class to all winning cells (that's one extra expression). With the same approach, I'm sure that Java could be as economical.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 it's not about how many lines your solution consists of, it's about reducing time complexity of the algorithm to check for a winner.

Comment: Why do you increase the moveCount if the position meant to be played was already played?

Comment: @PedroOtero This isn't fully fleshed out but this method is meant to be the function that handles the entire move.  So you'd call this method as the user has chosen their move.

Comment: so this solution is approximately O(N) seems like, every cell is checked

Comment: This solution wont work if the board is greater than 3x3 in its dimensions as a player could make a winning move on a tile where `if(board[x][i] != s)` evaluates to true (even though the player won) also diagonals could start where x!=y

Comment: I don't understand the if statement in the beginning. The board is a 2 dim array of the data type "State" , correct? if I am understanding this right - the if condition:  if(board[x][y] == State.Blank){board[x][y] = s; } would never get satisfied unless we initialize all cells in the board as "Blank" . Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Monnie_tester it's more of a few interesting ideas rather than a complete solution.  In a real app you'd wanna throw an error or something if the user tried to move in a spot that was already filled in, and definitely init all the spots as blank at the beginning.

Answer (score 55):

you can use a magic square http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MagicSquare.html if any row, column, or diag adds up to 15 then a player has won.

Comment: How does that translate to the tic-tac-toe game?

Comment: It's a neat bit of information that I didn't know, so I definitely thank you for the information. As Paul mentioned it's not immediately clear how that would help solve the problem at hand, but it feels like it might play into part of a more complete solution.

Comment: overlay it . 1 for white, 2 for black and multiply. if anything comes out to 15, then white has won and if it came out to 30 then black has won.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. I'm not sure what the Big O complexity of such an operation might be, however. Seems expensive? So far yours is the only answer that differs from the table method though.

Comment: Big O-wise, it's pretty cheap, especially if you mix it with Hardwareguy's cell-wise checking.  Each cell can only be in 4 possible tic-tac-toes: rowwise, columnwise, and two diagonals (slash and backslash).  So, once a move has been made, you only have to do at most 4 additions and comparisons.  Hardwareguy's answer requires 4(n-1) checks for each move, by comparison.

Comment: Couldn't we just do this with 1 and -1 and sum each row/colum/diag to see if it's n or -n?

Comment: If you try this, do not forget that you cannot simply check for a sum of 15 on X's squares, since longer non-winning combinations can also lead to a sum of 15 (ie 1+3+5+6 = 15 but non-winning)

Comment: You guys are glazing over the actual question. The real problem is "_algorithmically **finding** a column/row/diag_" not checking if its summation happens to equal some number. Once you have done so, (say with @Hardwareguy's approach) you could just as easily check if any (row/column/diag)'s tiles all == "X" or are all have a unicorn in them.

Answer (score 34):

How about this pseudocode:

After a player puts down a piece at position (x,y):

```
col=row=diag=rdiag=0
winner=false
for i=1 to n
  if cell[x,i]=player then col++
  if cell[i,y]=player then row++
  if cell[i,i]=player then diag++
  if cell[i,n-i+1]=player then rdiag++
if row=n or col=n or diag=n or rdiag=n then winner=true
```

I'd use an array of char [n,n], with O,X and space for empty.

1. simple.
2. One loop.
3. Five simple variables: 4 integers and one boolean.
4. Scales to any size of n.
5. Only checks current piece.
6. No magic. :)

Comment: if cell[i,n-(i+1)]=player then rdiag++; - Looks like with parentheses it will be correctly. Am I right?

Comment: @Pumych, no. If `i==1` and `n==3`,  `rdiag` must be checked at `(1, 3)` and `(1, 3-1+1)` is equal to the correct coordinates, but `(1, 3-(1+1))` no.

Comment: He might've been thinking that the cells were zero-indexed.

Comment: it was just some stuff off the top of my head.... it needs to be fixed during the actual writing of code :)

Answer (score 23):

This is similar to [Osama ALASSIRY's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056316/algorithm-for-determining-tic-tac-toe-game-over-java/1058804#1058804), but it trades constant-space and linear-time for linear-space and constant-time. That is, there's no looping after initialization.

Initialize a pair `(0,0)` for each row, each column, and the two diagonals (diagonal & anti-diagonal). These pairs represent the accumulated `(sum,sum)` of the pieces in the corresponding row, column, or diagonal, where

```
A piece from player A has value (1,0)
A piece from player B has value (0,1)
```

When a player places a piece, update the corresponding row pair, column pair, and diagonal pairs (if on the diagonals). If any newly updated row, column, or diagonal pair equals either `(n,0)` or `(0,n)` then either A or B won, respectively.

Asymptotic analysis:

```
O(1) time (per move)
O(n) space (overall)
```

For the memory use, you use `4*(n+1)` integers.

```
two_elements*n_rows + two_elements*n_columns +
two_elements*two_diagonals = 4*n + 4 integers = 4(n+1) integers
```

Exercise: Can you see how to test for a draw in O(1) time per-move? If so, you can end the game early on a draw.

Comment: I think this is better than Osama ALASSIRY's since his is roughly `O(sqrt(n))` time but has to be done after every move, where n is the size of the board. So you end up with `O(n^1.5)`. For this solution you get `O(n)` time overall.

Comment: nice way of seeing this, it makes sense to look at the actual "solutions"... for 3x3, you'd just have 8 pairs of "booleans" ... It can be even more space effective if it was 2 bits each... 16 bits needed and you can just bitwise OR 1 in the correct player shifted left to the correct place :)

Answer (score 19):

**Ultra-efficient Bit-boarding**

Let's store the game in a binary integer, and evaluate everything using just one step!

- We know that X's moves occupy 9 bits: `xxx xxx xxx`
- We know that O's moves occupy 9 bits: `ooo ooo ooo`

So, a board position could be represented in just 18 bits: `xoxoxo xoxoxo xoxoxo`

But, whilst this might look efficient, it doesn't help us with determining a win.  We need a more useful bit pattern... one that not only encodes the moves, but also encodes the rows, columns and diagonals in a reasonable way.

I would do this by using a clever integer value for each board position.

**Choosing a more useful representation**

First, we need a board notation, just so that we can discuss this.  So, similar to Chess, lets number the rows with letters and the columns with numbers - so we know which square we're talking about

|  | **1** | **2** | **3** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **A** | a1 | a2 | a3 |
| **B** | b1 | b2 | b3 |
| **C** | c1 | c2 | c3 |

And let's give each a binary value.

```
a1 = 100 000 000 100 000 000 100 000 ; Row A Col 1 (top left corner)
a2 = 010 000 000 000 100 000 000 000 ; Row A Col 2 (top edge)
a3 = 001 000 000 000 000 100 000 100 ; Row A Col 3 (top right corner)
b1 = 000 100 000 010 000 000 000 000 ; Row B Col 1 (left edge)
b2 = 000 010 000 000 010 000 010 010 ; Row B Col 2 (middle square)
b3 = 000 001 000 000 000 010 000 000 ; Row B Col 4 (right edge)
c1 = 000 000 100 001 000 000 000 001 ; Row C Col 1 (bottom left corner)
c2 = 000 000 010 000 001 000 000 000 ; Row C Col 2 (bottom edge)
c3 = 000 000 001 000 000 001 001 000 ; Row C Col 3 (bottom right corner)
```

... where, the binary values encode which rows, columns and diagonals the position appears in.  *(we'll look at how this works this later)*

We will use these values to build two representations of the game, one for X and one for O

- X starts with an empty board : `000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000`
- O starts with an empty board : `000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000`

**Let's follow X's moves** *(O would be the same principle)*

- X plays A1... so we OR (the X board) with value A1
- X plays A2... so we OR with value A2
- X plays A3... so we OR with value A3

What does that do to X's board value :

1. `a1 = 100 000 000 100 000 000 100 000` ... ORed with
2. `a2 = 010 000 000 000 100 000 000 000` ... ORed with
3. `a3 = 001 000 000 000 000 100 000 100` ... equals :

XB = `111 000 000 100 100 100 100 100`

Reading from left to right we see that X has :

- `111` (All positions) in Row 1 *(\o/ A win, Yay!)*
- `000` (No positions) in Row 2
- `000` (No positions) in Row 3
- `100` (One position) Only the first position of Column 1
- `100` (One position) Only the first position of Column 1
- `100` (One position) Only the first position of Column 1
- `100` (One position) Only the first position of Diagonal 1
- `100` (One position) Only the first position of Diagonal 2

You'll notice that whenever X (or O) has a winning line, then there will also be three consecutive bits in his board value.  Precisely Where those three bits are, dictates which row/column/diagonal he won on.

So, the trick now is to find a way to check for this (three consecutive bits set) condition in a single operation.

**Modifying the values to make detection easier**

To assist with this, let's change our bit representation so that there are always ZEROs between the groups of three (Because `001 110` is also three consecutive bits - but they are NOT a valid win ... so, a fixed zero spacer would break these up: `0 001 0 110`)

So, after adding some spacing ZEROes, we can be confident that ANY three consecutive set bits in X's or O's board value indicates a win!

So, our new binary values (with zero-padding) look like this :

- `a1 = 100 0 000 0 000 0 100 0 000 0 000 0 100 0 000 0` ; 0x80080080 (hex)
- `a2 = 010 0 000 0 000 0 000 0 100 0 000 0 000 0 000 0` ; 0x40008000
- `a3 = 001 0 000 0 000 0 000 0 000 0 100 0 000 0 100 0` ; 0x20000808
- `b1 = 000 0 100 0 000 0 010 0 000 0 000 0 000 0 000 0` ; 0x08040000
- `b2 = 000 0 010 0 000 0 000 0 010 0 000 0 010 0 010 0` ; 0x04004044
- `b3 = 000 0 001 0 000 0 000 0 000 0 010 0 000 0 000 0` ; 0x02000400
- `c1 = 000 0 000 0 100 0 001 0 000 0 000 0 000 0 001 0` ; 0x00820002
- `c2 = 000 0 000 0 010 0 000 0 001 0 000 0 000 0 000 0` ; 0x00402000
- `c3 = 000 0 000 0 001 0 000 0 000 0 001 0 001 0 000 0` ; 0x00200220

You'll notice that each "winline" of the board now requires 4 bits.

8 winlines x 4 bits each = 32 bits!  Isn't that convenient : )))))

**Parsing**

We could shift through all the bits looking for three consecutive bits, but that will take 32 shifts x 2 players... and a counter to keep track.  It's slow!

We could AND with 0xF, looking for the value 8+4+2=14.  And this would allow us to check 4 bits at a time.  Cutting the number of shifts by a quarter.  But again, this is slow!

So, instead, let's check ALL of the possibilities at once...

**Ultra-efficient win detection**

Imagine we wanted to evaluate the A3+A1+B2+C3 case (a win on the diagonal)

```
a1 = 100 0 000 0 000 0 100 0 000 0 000 0 100 0 000 0, OR
a3 = 001 0 000 0 000 0 000 0 000 0 100 0 000 0 100 0, OR
b2 = 000 0 010 0 000 0 000 0 010 0 000 0 010 0 010 0, OR
c3 = 000 0 000 0 001 0 000 0 000 0 001 0 001 0 000 0, =

XB = 101 0 010 0 001 0 100 0 010 0 101 0 111 0 110 0  (See the win, on Diagonal 1?)
```

Now, let's check it for a win, by efficiently merging three bits into one...

Simply use : `XB AND (XB << 1) AND (XB >> 1)`
in other words: XB ANDed with (XB shifted left) AND (XB shiftted right)

Let's try an example...

```
10100100001010000100101011101100 ; whitespaces removed for easy shifting
(AND)
01001000010100001001010111011000 ; XB shifted left
(AND)
01010010000101000010010101110110 ; XB shifted left
(Equals)
00000000000000000000000001000000
```

See that?  Any non-zero result means a win!

**But, where did they win**

Want to know where they won?  Well, you could just use a second table :

```
0x40000000 = RowA
0x04000000 = RowB
0x00400000 = RowC
0x00040000 = Col1
0x00004000 = Col2
0x00000400 = Col3
0x00000040 = Diag1
0x00000004 = Diag2
```

However, we can be smarter than that, as the pattern is VERY regular!

For example, in assembly you can use `BSF (Bit Scan Forward)` to find the number of leading zeros.  Then subtract 2 and then /4 (Shift Right 2) - to get a number between 0 and 8... which you can use as an index to look up into an array of win strings :

`{"wins the top row", "takes the middle row!", ... "steals the diagonal!" }`

This makes the whole game logic... from move checking, to board updating and right through to win/loss detection and an appropriate success message, all fit in a handful of ASM instructions.

... it's tiny, efficient and ultrafast!

**Checking whether a move is playable**

Obviously, ORing "X's board" with "O's board" = ALL POSITIONS

So, you can check if a move is valid quite easily.  If user chooses UpperLeft, this position has an integer value.  Just check the 'AND' of this Value with (XB OR OB)...

... if the result is nonzero, then the position is already in use.

**Conclusion**

If you're looking for efficient ways to process a board, don't start with a board object.  Try to discover some useful abstraction.

See if the states fit within an integer, and think about what an 'easy' bitmask to process would look like.  With some clever choice of integers to represent moves, positions or boards... you might find that the entire game can be played, evaluated and scored VERY efficiently - using simply bitwise logic.

**Closing apologies**

BTW I'm not a regular here on StackOverflow, so I hope this post wasn't too chaotic to follow.  Also, please be kind... "Human" is my second language and I'm not quite fluent yet ;)

Anyway, I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Love "'Human' is my second language and I'm not quite fluent yet"!

Comment: Really nice thorough answer, but the '0' spacer bit seems superfluous. The "Ultra-efficient win detection" can do without the spacer, by simply performing a final AND with '010 010 010 010 010 010 010 010'.  In fact, the very next section "But, where did they win" effectively creates these individual checks for the central bit, but of course with the added spacer.  Ie, '010 0' = 0x4.  By removing the spacer, all that's required is '010', but this doesn't give the pleasing flow of 4's for the win checks nor the convenient 32 bit board representation.  So methinks you are fluent in human.  ;-)

Comment: Underrated amazing answer

Comment: Holy boredom, but nonetheless my favorite answer!

Answer (score 17):

Heres my solution that I wrote for a project I'm working on in javascript.  If you don't mind the memory cost of a few arrays it's probably the fastest and simplest solution you'll find.  It assumes you know the position of the last move.

```
/*
 * Determines if the last move resulted in a win for either player
 * board: is an array representing the board
 * lastMove: is the boardIndex of the last (most recent) move
 *  these are the boardIndexes:
 *
 *   0 | 1 | 2
 *  ---+---+---
 *   3 | 4 | 5
 *  ---+---+---
 *   6 | 7 | 8
 * 
 * returns true if there was a win
 */
var winLines = [
    [[1, 2], [4, 8], [3, 6]],
    [[0, 2], [4, 7]],
    [[0, 1], [4, 6], [5, 8]],
    [[4, 5], [0, 6]],
    [[3, 5], [0, 8], [2, 6], [1, 7]],
    [[3, 4], [2, 8]],
    [[7, 8], [2, 4], [0, 3]],
    [[6, 8], [1, 4]],
    [[6, 7], [0, 4], [2, 5]]
];
function isWinningMove(board, lastMove) {
    var player = board[lastMove];
    for (var i = 0; i < winLines[lastMove].length; i++) {
        var line = winLines[lastMove][i];
        if(player === board[line[0]] && player === board[line[1]]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This would be the big hammer approach but it is indeed a viable solution, especially to site as one of a multitude of creative and working solutions to this problem. Also its short, elegant, and very readable - for a 3x3 grid (traditional Tx3) I like this algorithm.

Comment: This one is awesome!! I found that there is a little bug in the winning patterns, at the possition 8, the patterns should be [6,7], **[0,4]** and [2,5] : var winLines = [
    [[1, 2], [4, 8], [3, 6]],
    [[0, 2], [4, 7]],
    [[0, 1], [4, 6], [5, 8]],
    [[4, 5], [0, 6]],
    [[3, 5], [0, 8], [2, 6], [1, 7]],
    [[3, 4], [2, 8]],
    [[7, 8], [2, 4], [0, 3]],
    [[6, 8], [1, 4]],
    [[6, 7], [**0**, 4], [2, 5]]
];

Comment: It's not working for me. Do I have to keep track of the board? So if the board is an array with square 1 and 2 marked then `arr = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. I delete each time a square is marked? I'm using index staring at 1. I also adjusted all the winlines up by 1.

Answer (score 8):

Constant time solution, runs in O(8).

Store the state of the board as a binary number. The smallest bit (2^0) is the top left row of the board. Then it goes rightwards, then downwards.

I.E.

```
+-----------------+
| 2^0 | 2^1 | 2^2 |
|-----------------|
| 2^3 | 2^4 | 2^5 |
|-----------------|
| 2^6 | 2^7 | 2^8 |
+-----------------+
```

Each player has their own binary number to represent the state (because tic-tac-toe) has 3 states (X, O & blank) so a single binary number won't work to represent the state of the board for multiple players.

For example, a board like:

```
+-----------+
| X | O | X |
|-----------|
| O | X |   |
|-----------|
|   | O |   |
+-----------+

   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
X: 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
O: 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

Notice that the bits for player X are disjoint from the bits for player O, this is obvious because X can't put a piece where O has a piece and vice versa.

To check whether a player has won, we need to compare all the positions covered by that player to a position we know is a win-position. In this case, the easiest way to do that would be by AND-gating the player-position and the win-position and seeing if the two are equal.

```
boolean isWinner(short X) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        if ((X & winCombinations[i]) == winCombinations[i])
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

eg.

```
X: 111001010
W: 111000000 // win position, all same across first row.
------------
&: 111000000
```

Note: `X & W = W`, so X is in a win state.

This is a constant time solution, it depends only on the number of win-positions, because applying AND-gate is a constant time operation and the number of win-positions is finite.

It also simplifies the task of enumerating all valid board states, their just all the numbers representable by 9 bits. But of course you need an extra condition to guarantee a number is a valid board state (eg. `0b111111111` is a valid 9-bit number, but it isn't a valid board state because X has just taken all the turns).

The number of possible win positions can be generated on the fly, but here they are anyways.

```
short[] winCombinations = new short[] {
  // each row
  0b000000111,
  0b000111000,
  0b111000000,
  // each column
  0b100100100,
  0b010010010,
  0b001001001,
  // each diagonal
  0b100010001,
  0b001010100
};
```

To enumerate all board positions, you can run the following loop. Although I'll leave determining whether a number is a valid board state upto someone else.

NOTE: (2**9 - 1) = (2**8) + (2**7) + (2**6) + ... (2**1) + (2**0)

```
for (short X = 0; X < (Math.pow(2,9) - 1); X++)
   System.out.println(isWinner(X));
```

Comment: Please add more description and change the code so that it will exactly answer OP's question.

Comment: Excellent solution! Creating an array of 512 booleans can reduce isWinner to a single index reference. No loop.

Comment: Big O is meaningless when the board is fixed in size. O(8) = O(1).

Answer (score 7):

I just wrote this for my C programming class.

I am posting it because none of the other examples here will work with any size *rectangular* grid, and any number **N**-in-a-row consecutive marks to win.

You'll find my algorithm, such as it is, in the `checkWinner()` function. It doesn't use magic numbers or anything fancy to check for a winner, it simply uses four for loops - The code is well commented so I'll let it speak for itself I guess.

```
// This program will work with any whole number sized rectangular gameBoard.
// It checks for N marks in straight lines (rows, columns, and diagonals).
// It is prettiest when ROWS and COLS are single digit numbers.
// Try altering the constants for ROWS, COLS, and N for great fun!    

// PPDs come first

    #include <stdio.h>
    #define ROWS 9              // The number of rows our gameBoard array will have
    #define COLS 9              // The number of columns of the same - Single digit numbers will be prettier!
    #define N 3                 // This is the number of contiguous marks a player must have to win
    #define INITCHAR ' '        // This changes the character displayed (a ' ' here probably looks the best)
    #define PLAYER1CHAR 'X'     // Some marks are more aesthetically pleasing than others
    #define PLAYER2CHAR 'O'     // Change these lines if you care to experiment with them


// Function prototypes are next

    int playGame    (char gameBoard[ROWS][COLS]);               // This function allows the game to be replayed easily, as desired
    void initBoard  (char gameBoard[ROWS][COLS]);               // Fills the ROWSxCOLS character array with the INITCHAR character
    void printBoard (char gameBoard[ROWS][COLS]);               // Prints out the current board, now with pretty formatting and #s!
    void makeMove   (char gameBoard[ROWS][COLS], int player);   // Prompts for (and validates!) a move and stores it into the array
    int checkWinner (char gameBoard[ROWS][COLS], int player);   // Checks the current state of the board to see if anyone has won

// The starting line
int main (void)
{
    // Inits
    char gameBoard[ROWS][COLS];     // Our gameBoard is declared as a character array, ROWS x COLS in size
    int winner = 0;
    char replay;

    //Code
    do                              // This loop plays through the game until the user elects not to
    {
        winner = playGame(gameBoard);
        printf("\nWould you like to play again? Y for yes, anything else exits: ");

        scanf("%c",&replay);        // I have to use both a scanf() and a getchar() in
        replay = getchar();         // order to clear the input buffer of a newline char
                                    // (http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/121190-problem-do-while-loop-char.html)

    } while ( replay == 'y' || replay == 'Y' );

    // Housekeeping
    printf("\n");
    return winner;
}


int playGame(char gameBoard[ROWS][COLS])
{
    int turn = 0, player = 0, winner = 0, i = 0;

    initBoard(gameBoard);

    do
    {
        turn++;                                 // Every time this loop executes, a unique turn is about to be made
        player = (turn+1)%2+1;                  // This mod function alternates the player variable between 1 & 2 each turn
        makeMove(gameBoard,player);
        printBoard(gameBoard);
        winner = checkWinner(gameBoard,player);

        if (winner != 0)
        {
            printBoard(gameBoard);

            for (i=0;i<19-2*ROWS;i++)           // Formatting - works with the default shell height on my machine
                printf("\n");                   // Hopefully I can replace these with something that clears the screen for me

            printf("\n\nCongratulations Player %i, you've won with %i in a row!\n\n",winner,N);
            return winner;
        }

    } while ( turn < ROWS*COLS );                           // Once ROWS*COLS turns have elapsed

    printf("\n\nGame Over!\n\nThere was no Winner :-(\n");  // The board is full and the game is over
    return winner;
}


void initBoard (char gameBoard[ROWS][COLS])
{
    int row = 0, col = 0;

    for (row=0;row<ROWS;row++)
    {
        for (col=0;col<COLS;col++)
        {
            gameBoard[row][col] = INITCHAR;     // Fill the gameBoard with INITCHAR characters
        }
    }

    printBoard(gameBoard);                      // Having this here prints out the board before
    return;                             // the playGame function asks for the first move
}


void printBoard (char gameBoard[ROWS][COLS])    // There is a ton of formatting in here
{                                               // That I don't feel like commenting :P
    int row = 0, col = 0, i=0;                  // It took a while to fine tune
                                                // But now the output is something like:
    printf("\n");                               // 
                                                //    1   2   3
    for (row=0;row<ROWS;row++)                  // 1    |   |
    {                                           //   -----------
        if (row == 0)                           // 2    |   |
        {                                       //   -----------
            printf("  ");                       // 3    |   |

            for (i=0;i<COLS;i++)
            {
                printf(" %i  ",i+1);
            }

            printf("\n\n");
        }

        for (col=0;col<COLS;col++)
        {
            if (col==0)
                printf("%i ",row+1);

            printf(" %c ",gameBoard[row][col]);

            if (col<COLS-1)
                printf("|");
        }

        printf("\n");

        if (row < ROWS-1)
        {
            for(i=0;i<COLS-1;i++)
            {
                if(i==0)
                    printf("  ----");
                else
                    printf("----");
            }

            printf("---\n");
        }
    }

    return;
}


void makeMove (char gameBoard[ROWS][COLS],int player)
{
    int row = 0, col = 0, i=0;
    char currentChar;

    if (player == 1)                    // This gets the correct player's mark
        currentChar = PLAYER1CHAR;
    else
        currentChar = PLAYER2CHAR;

    for (i=0;i<21-2*ROWS;i++)           // Newline formatting again :-(
        printf("\n");

    printf("\nPlayer %i, please enter the column of your move: ",player);
    scanf("%i",&col);
    printf("Please enter the row of your move: ");
    scanf("%i",&row);

    row--;                              // These lines translate the user's rows and columns numbering
    col--;                              // (starting with 1) to the computer's (starting with 0)

    while(gameBoard[row][col] != INITCHAR || row > ROWS-1 || col > COLS-1)  // We are not using a do... while because
    {                                                                       // I wanted the prompt to change
        printBoard(gameBoard);
        for (i=0;i<20-2*ROWS;i++)
            printf("\n");
        printf("\nPlayer %i, please enter a valid move! Column first, then row.\n",player);
        scanf("%i %i",&col,&row);

        row--;                          // See above ^^^
        col--;
    }

    gameBoard[row][col] = currentChar;  // Finally, we store the correct mark into the given location
    return;                             // And pop back out of this function
}


int checkWinner(char gameBoard[ROWS][COLS], int player)     // I've commented the last (and the hardest, for me anyway)
{                                                           // check, which checks for backwards diagonal runs below >>>
    int row = 0, col = 0, i = 0;
    char currentChar;

    if (player == 1)
        currentChar = PLAYER1CHAR;
    else
        currentChar = PLAYER2CHAR;

    for ( row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)                       // This first for loop checks every row
    {
        for ( col = 0; col < (COLS-(N-1)); col++)           // And all columns until N away from the end
        {
            while (gameBoard[row][col] == currentChar)      // For consecutive rows of the current player's mark
            {
                col++;
                i++;
                if (i == N)
                {
                    return player;
                }
            }
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    for ( col = 0; col < COLS; col++)                       // This one checks for columns of consecutive marks
    {
        for ( row = 0; row < (ROWS-(N-1)); row++)
        {
            while (gameBoard[row][col] == currentChar)
            {
                row++;
                i++;
                if (i == N)
                {
                    return player;
                }
            }
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    for ( col = 0; col < (COLS - (N-1)); col++)             // This one checks for "forwards" diagonal runs
    {
        for ( row = 0; row < (ROWS-(N-1)); row++)
        {
            while (gameBoard[row][col] == currentChar)
            {
                row++;
                col++;
                i++;
                if (i == N)
                {
                    return player;
                }
            }
            i = 0;
        }
    }
                                                        // Finally, the backwards diagonals:
    for ( col = COLS-1; col > 0+(N-2); col--)           // Start from the last column and go until N columns from the first
    {                                                   // The math seems strange here but the numbers work out when you trace them
        for ( row = 0; row < (ROWS-(N-1)); row++)       // Start from the first row and go until N rows from the last
        {
            while (gameBoard[row][col] == currentChar)  // If the current player's character is there
            {
                row++;                                  // Go down a row
                col--;                                  // And back a column
                i++;                                    // The i variable tracks how many consecutive marks have been found
                if (i == N)                             // Once i == N
                {
                    return player;                      // Return the current player number to the
                }                                       // winnner variable in the playGame function
            }                                           // If it breaks out of the while loop, there weren't N consecutive marks
            i = 0;                                      // So make i = 0 again
        }                                               // And go back into the for loop, incrementing the row to check from
    }

    return 0;                                           // If we got to here, no winner has been detected,
}                                                       // so we pop back up into the playGame function

// The end!

// Well, almost.

// Eventually I hope to get this thing going
// with a dynamically sized array. I'll make
// the CONSTANTS into variables in an initGame
// function and allow the user to define them.
```

Comment: Very helpful. I was trying to find something more efficient, like if you know N = COL = ROW, you could reduce this to something much simpler, but I haven't found anything more efficient for arbitrary board size and N.

Answer (score 6):

If the board is *n* × *n* then there are *n* rows, *n* columns, and 2 diagonals. Check each of those for all-X's or all-O's to find a winner.

If it only takes *x* < *n* consecutive squares to win, then it's a little more complicated. The most obvious solution is to check each *x* × *x* square for a winner. Here's some code that demonstrates that.

(I didn't actually test this *cough*, but it *did* compile on the first try, yay me!)

```
public class TicTacToe
{
    public enum Square { X, O, NONE }

    /**
     * Returns the winning player, or NONE if the game has
     * finished without a winner, or null if the game is unfinished.
     */
    public Square findWinner(Square[][] board, int lengthToWin) {
        // Check each lengthToWin x lengthToWin board for a winner.    
        for (int top = 0; top <= board.length - lengthToWin; ++top) {
            int bottom = top + lengthToWin - 1;

            for (int left = 0; left <= board.length - lengthToWin; ++left) {
                int right = left + lengthToWin - 1;

                // Check each row.
                nextRow: for (int row = top; row <= bottom; ++row) {
                    if (board[row][left] == Square.NONE) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    for (int col = left; col <= right; ++col) {
                        if (board[row][col] != board[row][left]) {
                            continue nextRow;
                        }
                    }

                    return board[row][left];
                }

                // Check each column.
                nextCol: for (int col = left; col <= right; ++col) {
                    if (board[top][col] == Square.NONE) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    for (int row = top; row <= bottom; ++row) {
                        if (board[row][col] != board[top][col]) {
                            continue nextCol;
                        }
                    }

                    return board[top][col];
                }

                // Check top-left to bottom-right diagonal.
                diag1: if (board[top][left] != Square.NONE) {
                    for (int i = 1; i < lengthToWin; ++i) {
                        if (board[top+i][left+i] != board[top][left]) {
                            break diag1;
                        }
                    }

                    return board[top][left];
                }

                // Check top-right to bottom-left diagonal.
                diag2: if (board[top][right] != Square.NONE) {
                    for (int i = 1; i < lengthToWin; ++i) {
                        if (board[top+i][right-i] != board[top][right]) {
                            break diag2;
                        }
                    }

                    return board[top][right];
                }
            }
        }

        // Check for a completely full board.
        boolean isFull = true;

        full: for (int row = 0; row < board.length; ++row) {
            for (int col = 0; col < board.length; ++col) {
                if (board[row][col] == Square.NONE) {
                    isFull = false;
                    break full;
                }
            }
        }

        // The board is full.
        if (isFull) {
            return Square.NONE;
        }
        // The board is not full and we didn't find a solution.
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean. There would be (n*n*2) total answers in a traditional n=x game. This wouldn't work out if x (the number of consecutives needed to win) were less than n however. It's a good solution though, I like it better than the table for its extensibility.

Comment: I didn't mention the possibility of x < n in the original post though, so your answer is still spot on.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know Java that well, but I do know C, so I tried [adk's magic square idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056316/algorithm-for-determining-tic-tac-toe-game-over-java/1056320#1056320) (along with [Hardwareguy's search restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056316/algorithm-for-determining-tic-tac-toe-game-over-java/1056352#1056352)).

```
// tic-tac-toe.c
// to compile:
//  % gcc -o tic-tac-toe tic-tac-toe.c
// to run:
//  % ./tic-tac-toe
#include <stdio.h>

// the two types of marks available
typedef enum { Empty=2, X=0, O=1, NumMarks=2 } Mark;
char const MarkToChar[] = "XO ";

// a structure to hold the sums of each kind of mark
typedef struct { unsigned char of[NumMarks]; } Sum;

// a cell in the board, which has a particular value
#define MAGIC_NUMBER 15
typedef struct {
  Mark mark;
  unsigned char const value;
  size_t const num_sums;
  Sum * const sums[4];
} Cell;

#define NUM_ROWS 3
#define NUM_COLS 3

// create a sum for each possible tic-tac-toe
Sum row[NUM_ROWS] = {0};
Sum col[NUM_COLS] = {0};
Sum nw_diag = {0};
Sum ne_diag = {0};

// initialize the board values so any row, column, or diagonal adds to
// MAGIC_NUMBER, and so they each record their sums in the proper rows, columns,
// and diagonals
Cell board[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS] = { 
  { 
    { Empty, 8, 3, { &row[0], &col[0], &nw_diag } },
    { Empty, 1, 2, { &row[0], &col[1] } },
    { Empty, 6, 3, { &row[0], &col[2], &ne_diag } },
  },
  { 
    { Empty, 3, 2, { &row[1], &col[0] } },
    { Empty, 5, 4, { &row[1], &col[1], &nw_diag, &ne_diag } },
    { Empty, 7, 2, { &row[1], &col[2] } },
  },
  { 
    { Empty, 4, 3, { &row[2], &col[0], &ne_diag } },
    { Empty, 9, 2, { &row[2], &col[1] } },
    { Empty, 2, 3, { &row[2], &col[2], &nw_diag } },
  }
};

// print the board
void show_board(void)
{
  size_t r, c;
  for (r = 0; r < NUM_ROWS; r++) 
  {
    if (r > 0) { printf("---+---+---\n"); }
    for (c = 0; c < NUM_COLS; c++) 
    {
      if (c > 0) { printf("|"); }
      printf(" %c ", MarkToChar[board[r][c].mark]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}


// run the game, asking the player for inputs for each side
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  size_t m;
  show_board();
  printf("Enter moves as \"<row> <col>\" (no quotes, zero indexed)\n");
  for( m = 0; m < NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS; m++ )
  {
    Mark const mark = (Mark) (m % NumMarks);
    size_t c, r;

    // read the player's move
    do
    {
      printf("%c's move: ", MarkToChar[mark]);
      fflush(stdout);
      scanf("%d %d", &r, &c);
      if (r >= NUM_ROWS || c >= NUM_COLS)
      {
        printf("illegal move (off the board), try again\n");
      }
      else if (board[r][c].mark != Empty)
      {
        printf("illegal move (already taken), try again\n");
      }
      else
      {
        break;
      }
    }
    while (1);

    {
      Cell * const cell = &(board[r][c]);
      size_t s;

      // update the board state
      cell->mark = mark;
      show_board();

      // check for tic-tac-toe
      for (s = 0; s < cell->num_sums; s++)
      {
        cell->sums[s]->of[mark] += cell->value;
        if (cell->sums[s]->of[mark] == MAGIC_NUMBER)
        {
          printf("tic-tac-toe! %c wins!\n", MarkToChar[mark]);
          goto done;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  printf("stalemate... nobody wins :(\n");
done:
  return 0;
}
```

It compiles and tests well.

```
% gcc -o tic-tac-toe tic-tac-toe.c
% ./tic-tac-toe
     |   |
  ---+---+---
     |   |
  ---+---+---
     |   |
  Enter moves as " " (no quotes, zero indexed)
  X's move: 1 2
     |   |
  ---+---+---
     |   | X
  ---+---+---
     |   |
  O's move: 1 2
  illegal move (already taken), try again
  O's move: 3 3
  illegal move (off the board), try again
  O's move: 2 2
     |   |
  ---+---+---
     |   | X
  ---+---+---
     |   | O
  X's move: 1 0
     |   |
  ---+---+---
   X |   | X
  ---+---+---
     |   | O
  O's move: 1 1
     |   |
  ---+---+---
   X | O | X
  ---+---+---
     |   | O
  X's move: 0 0
   X |   |
  ---+---+---
   X | O | X
  ---+---+---
     |   | O
  O's move: 2 0
   X |   |
  ---+---+---
   X | O | X
  ---+---+---
   O |   | O
  X's move: 2 1
   X |   |
  ---+---+---
   X | O | X
  ---+---+---
   O | X | O
  O's move: 0 2
   X |   | O
  ---+---+---
   X | O | X
  ---+---+---
   O | X | O
  tic-tac-toe! O wins!
% ./tic-tac-toe
     |   |
  ---+---+---
     |   |
  ---+---+---
     |   |
  Enter moves as " " (no quotes, zero indexed)
  X's move: 0 0
   X |   |
  ---+---+---
     |   |
  ---+---+---
     |   |
  O's move: 0 1
   X | O |
  ---+---+---
     |   |
  ---+---+---
     |   |
  X's move: 0 2
   X | O | X
  ---+---+---
     |   |
  ---+---+---
     |   |
  O's move: 1 0
   X | O | X
  ---+---+---
   O |   |
  ---+---+---
     |   |
  X's move: 1 1
   X | O | X
  ---+---+---
   O | X |
  ---+---+---
     |   |
  O's move: 2 0
   X | O | X
  ---+---+---
   O | X |
  ---+---+---
   O |   |
  X's move: 2 1
   X | O | X
  ---+---+---
   O | X |
  ---+---+---
   O | X |
  O's move: 2 2
   X | O | X
  ---+---+---
   O | X |
  ---+---+---
   O | X | O
  X's move: 1 2
   X | O | X
  ---+---+---
   O | X | X
  ---+---+---
   O | X | O
  stalemate... nobody wins :(
%
```

That was fun, thanks!

Actually, thinking about it, you don't need a magic square, just a count for each row/column/diagonal.  This is a little easier than generalizing a magic square to `n` × `n` matrices, since you just need to count to `n`.

Answer (score 3):

I was asked the same question in one of my interviews.
My thoughts:
Initialize the matrix with 0.
Keep 3 arrays
1)sum_row (size n)
2) sum_column (size n)
3) diagonal (size 2)

For each move by (X) decrement the box value by 1 and for each move by (0) increment it by 1.
At any point if the row/column/diagonal which has been modified in current move has sum either -3 or +3 means somebody has won the game.
For a draw we can use above approach to keep the moveCount variable.

Do you think I am missing something ?

Edit: Same can be used for nxn matrix. Sum should be even +3 or -3.

Answer (score 3):

I like this algorithm as it uses a 1x9 vs 3x3 representation of the board.

```
private int[] board = new int[9];
private static final int[] START = new int[] { 0, 3, 6, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2 };
private static final int[] INCR  = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2 };
private static int SIZE = 3;
/**
 * Determines if there is a winner in tic-tac-toe board.
 * @return {@code 0} for draw, {@code 1} for 'X', {@code -1} for 'Y'
 */
public int hasWinner() {
    for (int i = 0; i < START.length; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            sum += board[START[i] + j * INCR[i]];
        }
        if (Math.abs(sum) == SIZE) {
            return sum / SIZE;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like this approach the most. It would have helped if you'd explained what "start" and "incr" meant. (It's a way of expressing all the "lines" as a starting index and number of indexes to skip.)

Comment: Please add more explanation. How did you come up with this code?

Answer (score 2):

a non-loop way to determine if the point was on the anti diag:

```
`if (x + y == n - 1)`
```

Answer (score 2):

I am late the party, but I wanted to point out one benefit that I found to using a [magic square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square), namely that it can be used to get a reference to the square that would cause the win or loss on the next turn, rather than just being used to calculate when a game is over.

Take this magic square:

```
4 9 2
3 5 7
8 1 6
```

First, set up an `scores` array that is incremented every time a move is made. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4199023/1830334) for details. Now if we illegally play X twice in a row at [0,0] and [0,1], then the `scores` array looks like this:

```
[7, 0, 0, 4, 3, 0, 4, 0];
```

And the board looks like this:

```
X . .
X . .
. . .
```

Then, all we have to do in order to get a reference to which square to win/block on is:

```
get_winning_move = function() {
  for (var i = 0, i < scores.length; i++) {
    // keep track of the number of times pieces were added to the row
    // subtract when the opposite team adds a piece
    if (scores[i].inc === 2) {
      return 15 - state[i].val; // 8
    }
  }
}
```

In reality, the implementation requires a few additional tricks, like handling numbered keys (in JavaScript), but I found it pretty straightforward and enjoyed the recreational math.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example implementation in React: [CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-herschel-oo9tv).

The algorithm is quite straightforward:

```
For every move:
   checkDiagonals()
   checkVerticals()
   checkHorizontals()
```

Assigning `0` for an "O" input and `1` for an "X" input. The result of the check functions can be either `0`, or `1`, or `2` (draw).

Here's the implementation:

```
    const checkDiagonals = () => {
        if ((state[0][0] === val && state[1][1] === val && state[2][2] === val) ||
            (state[0][2] === val && state[1][1] === val && state[2][0] === val)) {
            return val;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    const checkVerticals = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            if (state[0][i] === val && state[1][i] === val && state[2][i] === val) {
                return val;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    const checkHorizontals = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            if (state[i][0] === val && state[i][1] === val && state[i][2] === val) {
                return val;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Then all is left, is to have a function that will trigger on every single user input:

```
const updateWinningPlayer = () => {

    const diagonals = checkDiagonals();
    const verticals = checkVerticals();
    const horizontals = checkHorizontals();

    if (diagonals !== -1) {
        setWinner(diagonals)
        return;
    }

    if (verticals !== -1) {
        setWinner(verticals);
        return;
    }

    if (horizontals !== -1) {
        setWinner(horizontals);
        return;
    }

    if (isDraw()) {
        setWinner(2);
    }
}
```

And there you have it!

[image: TicTacToe image]

GitHub repo link: https://github.com/mkotsollaris/tic-tac-toe

Answer (score 1):

I made some optimization in the row, col, diagonal checks. Its mainly decided in the first nested loop if we need to check a particular column or diagonal. So, we avoid checking of columns or diagonals saving time. This makes big impact when the board size is more and a significant number of the cells are not filled.

Here is the java code for that.

```
    int gameState(int values[][], int boardSz) {


    boolean colCheckNotRequired[] = new boolean[boardSz];//default is false
    boolean diag1CheckNotRequired = false;
    boolean diag2CheckNotRequired = false;
    boolean allFilled = true;


    int x_count = 0;
    int o_count = 0;
    /* Check rows */
    for (int i = 0; i < boardSz; i++) {
        x_count = o_count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < boardSz; j++) {
            if(values[i][j] == x_val)x_count++;
            if(values[i][j] == o_val)o_count++;
            if(values[i][j] == 0)
            {
                colCheckNotRequired[j] = true;
                if(i==j)diag1CheckNotRequired = true;
                if(i + j == boardSz - 1)diag2CheckNotRequired = true;
                allFilled = false;
                //No need check further
                break;
            }
        }
        if(x_count == boardSz)return X_WIN;
        if(o_count == boardSz)return O_WIN;         
    }


    /* check cols */
    for (int i = 0; i < boardSz; i++) {
        x_count = o_count = 0;
        if(colCheckNotRequired[i] == false)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < boardSz; j++) {
                if(values[j][i] == x_val)x_count++;
                if(values[j][i] == o_val)o_count++;
                //No need check further
                if(values[i][j] == 0)break;
            }
            if(x_count == boardSz)return X_WIN;
            if(o_count == boardSz)return O_WIN;
        }
    }

    x_count = o_count = 0;
    /* check diagonal 1 */
    if(diag1CheckNotRequired == false)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSz; i++) {
            if(values[i][i] == x_val)x_count++;
            if(values[i][i] == o_val)o_count++;
            if(values[i][i] == 0)break;
        }
        if(x_count == boardSz)return X_WIN;
        if(o_count == boardSz)return O_WIN;
    }

    x_count = o_count = 0;
    /* check diagonal 2 */
    if( diag2CheckNotRequired == false)
    {
        for (int i = boardSz - 1,j = 0; i >= 0 && j < boardSz; i--,j++) {
            if(values[j][i] == x_val)x_count++;
            if(values[j][i] == o_val)o_count++;
            if(values[j][i] == 0)break;
        }
        if(x_count == boardSz)return X_WIN;
        if(o_count == boardSz)return O_WIN;
        x_count = o_count = 0;
    }

    if( allFilled == true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSz; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < boardSz; j++) {
                if (values[i][j] == 0) {
                    allFilled = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (allFilled == false) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (allFilled)
        return DRAW;

    return INPROGRESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a really simple way to check.

```
    public class Game() { 

    Game player1 = new Game('x');
    Game player2 = new Game('o');

    char piece;

    Game(char piece) {
       this.piece = piece;
    }

public void checkWin(Game player) {

    // check horizontal win
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i += 3) {

        if (board[i] == player.piece &&
                board[i + 1] == player.piece &&
                board[i + 2] == player.piece)
            endGame(player);
    }

    // check vertical win
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {

        if (board[i] == player.piece &&
                board[i + 3] == player.piece &&
                board[i + 6] == player.piece)
            endGame(player);
    }

    // check diagonal win
    if ((board[0] == player.piece &&
            board[4] == player.piece &&
            board[8] == player.piece) ||
            board[2] == player.piece &&
            board[4] == player.piece &&
            board[6] == player.piece)
        endGame(player);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Another option: generate your table with code. Up to symmetry, there are only three ways to win: edge row, middle row, or diagonal. Take those three and spin them around every way possible:

```
def spin(g): return set([g, turn(g), turn(turn(g)), turn(turn(turn(g)))])
def turn(g): return tuple(tuple(g[y][x] for y in (0,1,2)) for x in (2,1,0))

X,s = 'X.'
XXX = X, X, X
sss = s, s, s

ways_to_win = (  spin((XXX, sss, sss))
               | spin((sss, XXX, sss))
               | spin(((X,s,s),
                       (s,X,s),
                       (s,s,X))))
```

These symmetries can have more uses in your game-playing code: if you get to a board you've already seen a rotated version of, you can just take the cached value or cached best move from that one (and unrotate it back). This is usually much faster than evaluating the game subtree.

(Flipping left and right can help the same way; it wasn't needed here because the set of rotations of the winning patterns is mirror-symmetric.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I came up with, this stores the symbols as chars and uses the char's int value to figure out if X or O has won (look at the Referee's code)

```
public class TicTacToe {
    public static final char BLANK = '\u0000';
    private final char[][] board;
    private int moveCount;
    private Referee referee;

    public TicTacToe(int gridSize) {
        if (gridSize < 3)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("TicTacToe board size has to be minimum 3x3 grid");
        board = new char[gridSize][gridSize];
        referee = new Referee(gridSize);
    }

    public char[][] displayBoard() {
        return board.clone();
    }

    public String move(int x, int y) {
        if (board[x][y] != BLANK)
            return "(" + x + "," + y + ") is already occupied";
        board[x][y] = whoseTurn();
        return referee.isGameOver(x, y, board[x][y], ++moveCount);
    }

    private char whoseTurn() {
        return moveCount % 2 == 0 ? 'X' : 'O';
    }

    private class Referee {
        private static final int NO_OF_DIAGONALS = 2;
        private static final int MINOR = 1;
        private static final int PRINCIPAL = 0;
        private final int gridSize;
        private final int[] rowTotal;
        private final int[] colTotal;
        private final int[] diagonalTotal;

        private Referee(int size) {
            gridSize = size;
            rowTotal = new int[size];
            colTotal = new int[size];
            diagonalTotal = new int[NO_OF_DIAGONALS];
        }

        private String isGameOver(int x, int y, char symbol, int moveCount) {
            if (isWinningMove(x, y, symbol))
                return symbol + " won the game!";
            if (isBoardCompletelyFilled(moveCount))
                return "Its a Draw!";
            return "continue";
        }

        private boolean isBoardCompletelyFilled(int moveCount) {
            return moveCount == gridSize * gridSize;
        }

        private boolean isWinningMove(int x, int y, char symbol) {
            if (isPrincipalDiagonal(x, y) && allSymbolsMatch(symbol, diagonalTotal, PRINCIPAL))
                return true;
            if (isMinorDiagonal(x, y) && allSymbolsMatch(symbol, diagonalTotal, MINOR))
                return true;
            return allSymbolsMatch(symbol, rowTotal, x) || allSymbolsMatch(symbol, colTotal, y);
        }

        private boolean allSymbolsMatch(char symbol, int[] total, int index) {
            total[index] += symbol;
            return total[index] / gridSize == symbol;
        }

        private boolean isPrincipalDiagonal(int x, int y) {
            return x == y;
        }

        private boolean isMinorDiagonal(int x, int y) {
            return x + y == gridSize - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Also here are my unit tests to validate it actually works

```
import static com.agilefaqs.tdd.demo.TicTacToe.BLANK;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TicTacToeTest {
    private TicTacToe game = new TicTacToe(3);

    @Test
    public void allCellsAreEmptyInANewGame() {
        assertBoardIs(new char[][] { { BLANK, BLANK, BLANK },
                { BLANK, BLANK, BLANK },
                { BLANK, BLANK, BLANK } });
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void boardHasToBeMinimum3x3Grid() {
        new TicTacToe(2);
    }

    @Test
    public void firstPlayersMoveMarks_X_OnTheBoard() {
        assertEquals("continue", game.move(1, 1));
        assertBoardIs(new char[][] { { BLANK, BLANK, BLANK },
                { BLANK, 'X', BLANK },
                { BLANK, BLANK, BLANK } });
    }

    @Test
    public void secondPlayersMoveMarks_O_OnTheBoard() {
        game.move(1, 1);
        assertEquals("continue", game.move(2, 2));
        assertBoardIs(new char[][] { { BLANK, BLANK, BLANK },
                { BLANK, 'X', BLANK },
                { BLANK, BLANK, 'O' } });
    }

    @Test
    public void playerCanOnlyMoveToAnEmptyCell() {
        game.move(1, 1);
        assertEquals("(1,1) is already occupied", game.move(1, 1));
    }

    @Test
    public void firstPlayerWithAllSymbolsInOneRowWins() {
        game.move(0, 0);
        game.move(1, 0);
        game.move(0, 1);
        game.move(2, 1);
        assertEquals("X won the game!", game.move(0, 2));
    }

    @Test
    public void firstPlayerWithAllSymbolsInOneColumnWins() {
        game.move(1, 1);
        game.move(0, 0);
        game.move(2, 1);
        game.move(1, 0);
        game.move(2, 2);
        assertEquals("O won the game!", game.move(2, 0));
    }

    @Test
    public void firstPlayerWithAllSymbolsInPrincipalDiagonalWins() {
        game.move(0, 0);
        game.move(1, 0);
        game.move(1, 1);
        game.move(2, 1);
        assertEquals("X won the game!", game.move(2, 2));
    }

    @Test
    public void firstPlayerWithAllSymbolsInMinorDiagonalWins() {
        game.move(0, 2);
        game.move(1, 0);
        game.move(1, 1);
        game.move(2, 1);
        assertEquals("X won the game!", game.move(2, 0));
    }

    @Test
    public void whenAllCellsAreFilledTheGameIsADraw() {
        game.move(0, 2);
        game.move(1, 1);
        game.move(1, 0);
        game.move(2, 1);
        game.move(2, 2);
        game.move(0, 0);
        game.move(0, 1);
        game.move(1, 2);
        assertEquals("Its a Draw!", game.move(2, 0));
    }

    private void assertBoardIs(char[][] expectedBoard) {
        assertArrayEquals(expectedBoard, game.displayBoard());
    }
}
```

Full solution: https://github.com/nashjain/tictactoe/tree/master/java

Answer (score 0):

How about a following approach for 9 slots? Declare 9 integer variables for a 3x3 matrix (a1,a2....a9) where a1,a2,a3 represent row-1 and a1,a4,a7 would form column-1 (you get the idea). Use '1' to indicate Player-1 and '2' to indicate Player-2.

There are 8 possible win combinations: 
    Win-1: a1+a2+a3 (answer could be 3 or 6 based on which player won)
    Win-2: a4+a5+a6
    Win-3: a7+a8+a9
    Win-4: a1+a4+a7
    ....
    Win-7: a1+a5+a9
    Win-8: a3+a5+a7

Now we know that if player one crosses a1 then we need to reevaluate sum of 3 variables: Win-1, Win-4 and Win-7. Whichever 'Win-?' variables reaches 3 or 6 first wins the game. If Win-1 variable reaches 6 first then Player-2 wins.

I do understand that this solution is not scalable easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you have boarder field 5*5 for examle, I used next method of checking:

```
public static boolean checkWin(char symb) {
  int SIZE = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE-1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <SIZE-1 ; j++) {
                //vertical checking
            if (map[0][j] == symb && map[1][j] == symb && map[2][j] == symb && map[3][j] == symb && map[4][j] == symb) return true;      // j=0
            }
            //horisontal checking
            if(map[i][0] == symb && map[i][1] == symb && map[i][2] == symb && map[i][3] == symb && map[i][4] == symb) return true;  // i=0
        }
        //diagonal checking (5*5)
        if (map[0][0] == symb && map[1][1] == symb && map[2][2] == symb && map[3][3] == symb && map[4][4] == symb) return true;
        if (map[4][0] == symb && map[3][1] == symb && map[2][2] == symb && map[1][3] == symb && map[0][4] == symb) return true;

        return false; 
        }
```

I think, it's more clear, but probably is not the most optimal way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using an 2-dimensional array:

```
private static final int dimension = 3;
private static final int[][] board = new int[dimension][dimension];
private static final int xwins = dimension * 1;
private static final int owins = dimension * -1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;
    boolean keepPlaying = true;
    boolean xsTurn = true;
    while (keepPlaying) {
        xsTurn = (count % 2 == 0);
        System.out.print("Enter i-j in the format:");
        if (xsTurn) {
            System.out.println(" X plays: ");
        } else {
            System.out.println(" O plays: ");
        }
        String result = null;
        while (result == null) {
            result = parseInput(scanner, xsTurn);
        }
        String[] xy = result.split(",");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(xy[0]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(xy[1]);
        keepPlaying = makeMove(xsTurn, x, y);
        count++;
    }
    if (xsTurn) {
        System.out.print("X");
    } else {
        System.out.print("O");
    }
    System.out.println(" WON");
    printArrayBoard(board);
}

private static String parseInput(Scanner scanner, boolean xsTurn) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] values = line.split("-");
    int x = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
    boolean alreadyPlayed = alreadyPlayed(x, y);
    String result = null;
    if (alreadyPlayed) {
        System.out.println("Already played in this x-y. Retry");
    } else {
        result = "" + x + "," + y;
    }
    return result;
}

private static boolean alreadyPlayed(int x, int y) {
    System.out.println("x-y: " + x + "-" + y + " board[x][y]: " + board[x][y]);
    if (board[x][y] != 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static void printArrayBoard(int[][] board) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
        int[] height = board[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
            System.out.print(height[j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private static boolean makeMove(boolean xo, int x, int y) {
    if (xo) {
        board[x][y] = 1;
    } else {
        board[x][y] = -1;
    }
    boolean didWin = checkBoard();
    if (didWin) {
        System.out.println("keep playing");
    }
    return didWin;
}

private static boolean checkBoard() {
    //check horizontal
    int[] horizontalTotal = new int[dimension];
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
        int[] height = board[i];
        int total = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
            total += height[j];
        }
        horizontalTotal[i] = total;
    }
    for (int a = 0; a < horizontalTotal.length; a++) {
        if (horizontalTotal[a] == xwins || horizontalTotal[a] == owins) {
            System.out.println("horizontal");
            return false;
        }
    }
    //check vertical
    int[] verticalTotal = new int[dimension];

    for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
            total += board[i][j];
        }
        verticalTotal[j] = total;
    }
    for (int a = 0; a < verticalTotal.length; a++) {
        if (verticalTotal[a] == xwins || verticalTotal[a] == owins) {
            System.out.println("vertical");
            return false;
        }
    }
    //check diagonal
    int total1 = 0;
    int total2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
            if (i == j) {
                total1 += board[i][j];
            }
            if (i == (dimension - 1 - j)) {
                total2 += board[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    if (total1 == xwins || total1 == owins) {
        System.out.println("diagonal 1");
        return false;
    }
    if (total2 == xwins || total2 == owins) {
        System.out.println("diagonal 2");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this approach is published yet. This should work for any m*n board and a player is supposed to fill "**winnerPos**" consecutive position. The idea is based on running window.

```
private boolean validateWinner(int x, int y, int player) {
    //same col
    int low = x-winnerPos-1;
    int high = low;
    while(high <= x+winnerPos-1) {
        if(isValidPos(high, y) && isFilledPos(high, y, player)) {
            high++;
            if(high - low == winnerPos) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            low = high + 1;
            high = low;
        }
    }

    //same row
    low = y-winnerPos-1;
    high = low;
    while(high <= y+winnerPos-1) {
        if(isValidPos(x, high) && isFilledPos(x, high, player)) {
            high++;
            if(high - low == winnerPos) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            low = high + 1;
            high = low;
        }
    }
    if(high - low == winnerPos) {
        return true;
    }

    //diagonal 1
    int lowY = y-winnerPos-1;
    int highY = lowY;
    int lowX = x-winnerPos-1;
    int highX = lowX;
    while(highX <= x+winnerPos-1 && highY <= y+winnerPos-1) {
        if(isValidPos(highX, highY) && isFilledPos(highX, highY, player)) {
            highX++;
            highY++;
            if(highX - lowX == winnerPos) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            lowX = highX + 1;
            lowY = highY + 1;
            highX = lowX;
            highY = lowY;
        }
    }

    //diagonal 2
    lowY = y+winnerPos-1;
    highY = lowY;
    lowX = x-winnerPos+1;
    highX = lowX;
    while(highX <= x+winnerPos-1 && highY <= y+winnerPos-1) {
        if(isValidPos(highX, highY) && isFilledPos(highX, highY, player)) {
            highX++;
            highY--;
            if(highX - lowX == winnerPos) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            lowX = highX + 1;
            lowY = highY + 1;
            highX = lowX;
            highY = lowY;
        }
    }
    if(highX - lowX == winnerPos) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isValidPos(int x, int y) {
    return x >= 0 && x < row && y >= 0 && y< col;
}
public boolean isFilledPos(int x, int y, int p) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    return arena[x][y] == p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share what I did in Javascript. My idea is to have search directions; in grid it could be 8 directions, but search should be bi-directional so 8 / 2 = 4 directions. When a player does its move, the search starts from the location. It searches 4 different bi-directions until its value is different from the player's stone(O or X).

Per a bi-direction search, two values can be added but need to subtract one because starting point was duplicated.

```
getWin(x,y,value,searchvector) {
if (arguments.length==2) {
  var checkTurn = this.state.squares[y][x];
  var searchdirections = [[-1,-1],[0,-1],[1,-1],[-1,0]];
  return searchdirections.reduce((maxinrow,searchdirection)=>Math.max(this.getWin(x,y,checkTurn,searchdirection)+this.getWin(x,y,checkTurn,[-searchdirection[0],-searchdirection[1]]),maxinrow),0);
} else {
  if (this.state.squares[y][x]===value) {
    var result = 1;
    if (
      x+searchvector[0] >= 0 && x+searchvector[0] < 3 && 
      y+searchvector[1] >= 0 && y+searchvector[1] < 3
      ) result += this.getWin(x+searchvector[0],y+searchvector[1],value,searchvector);
    return result;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

}

This function can be used with two parameters (x,y), which are coordinates of the last move. In initial execution, it calls four bi-direction searches recursively with 4 parameters. All results are returned as lengths and the function finally picks the maximum length among 4 search bi-directions.

```js
class Square extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value:null};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="square" onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(x,y) {
    return <Square value={this.state.squares[y][x]} onClick={() => this.handleClick(x,y)} />;
  }
  handleClick(x,y) {
    const squares = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.squares));
    if (!squares[y][x] && !this.state.winner) {
      squares[y][x] = this.setTurn();
      this.setState({squares: squares},()=>{
        console.log(`Max in a row made by last move(${squares[y][x]}): ${this.getWin(x,y)-1}`);
        if (this.getWin(x,y)==4) this.setState({winner:squares[y][x]});
      });
    }
  }
  setTurn() {
    var prevTurn = this.state.turn;
    this.setState({turn:prevTurn == 'X' ? 'O':'X'});
    return prevTurn;
  }
  
  getWin(x,y,value,searchvector) {
    if (arguments.length==2) {
      var checkTurn = this.state.squares[y][x];
      var searchdirections = [[-1,-1],[0,-1],[1,-1],[-1,0]];
      return searchdirections.reduce((maxinrow,searchdirection)=>Math.max(this.getWin(x,y,checkTurn,searchdirection)+this.getWin(x,y,checkTurn,[-searchdirection[0],-searchdirection[1]]),maxinrow),0);
    } else {
      if (this.state.squares[y][x]===value) {
        var result = 1;
        if (
          x+searchvector[0] >= 0 && x+searchvector[0] < 3 && 
          y+searchvector[1] >= 0 && y+searchvector[1] < 3
          ) result += this.getWin(x+searchvector[0],y+searchvector[1],value,searchvector);
        return result;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      squares: Array(3).fill(Array(3).fill(null)),
      turn: 'X',
      winner: null
    };
  }
  render() {
    const status = !this.state.winner?`Next player: ${this.state.turn}`:`${this.state.winner} won!`;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0,0)}
          {this.renderSquare(0,1)}
          {this.renderSquare(0,2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(1,0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1,1)}
          {this.renderSquare(1,2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(2,0)}
          {this.renderSquare(2,1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2,2)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{/* status */}</div>
          <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px "Century Gothic", Futura, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
}

ol, ul {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.board-row:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.status {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.square {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  float: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 34px;
}

.square:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.kbd-navigation .square:focus {
  background: #ddd;
}

.game {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.game-info {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="errors" style="
  background: #c00;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  margin: -20px -20px 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
"></div>
<div id="root"></div>
<script>
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  document.body.classList.add('mouse-navigation');
  document.body.classList.remove('kbd-navigation');
});
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    document.body.classList.add('kbd-navigation');
    document.body.classList.remove('mouse-navigation');
  }
});
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'A' && e.target.getAttribute('href') === '#') {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
window.onerror = function(message, source, line, col, error) {
  var text = error ? error.stack || error : message + ' (at ' + source + ':' + line + ':' + col + ')';
  errors.textContent += text + '\n';
  errors.style.display = '';
};
console.error = (function(old) {
  return function error() {
    errors.textContent += Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(' ') + '\n';
    errors.style.display = '';
    old.apply(this, arguments);
  }
})(console.error);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a tic-tac-toe question on another thread that I can't find now, but I found this, so here was my tic-tac-toe simulator I whipped up after reading the question:

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep

# Tic-tac-toe simulator
# The grid:
#  0 | 1 | 2
# -----------
#  3 | 4 | 5
# -----------
#  6 | 7 | 8
# -----------

# create winning lines
winlines = tuple(
    map(
        set,
        (
            (0, 1, 2),  # across
            (3, 4, 5),
            (6, 7, 8),
            (0, 3, 6),  # down
            (1, 4, 7),
            (2, 5, 8),
            (0, 4, 8),  # diagonals
            (2, 4, 6),
        ),
    )
)

for trials in range(10):
    # clear the table
    available = list(range(9))  # 9 positions 0-8
    xPlacement = set()
    oPlacement = set()

    winner = None

    while len(available):
        index = randint(0, len(available) - 1)
        move = available[index]
        if index < len(available) - 1:
            available[index] = available.pop()
        else:
            available.pop()
        print("X takes ", move)
        xPlacement.add(move)
        if any(((xPlacement & winline) == winline) for winline in winlines):
            winner = "X"
            break
        if len(available) == 0:
            break

        index = randint(0, len(available) - 1)
        move = available[index]
        if index < len(available) - 1:
            available[index] = available.pop()
        else:
            available.pop()
        print("O takes ", move)
        oPlacement.add(move)
        if any(((oPlacement & winline) == winline) for winline in winlines):
            winner = "O"
            break

    print(
        " {} | {} | {}\n-----------\n {} | {} | {}\n-----------\n {} | {} | {}".format(
            *[
                "X" if pos in xPlacement else "O" if pos in oPlacement else " "
                for pos in range(9)
            ]
        )
    )
    if winner:
        print(f"{winner} wins!")
    else:
        print("It's a tie!")
    sleep(1)
```

Answer (score -2):

I developed an algorithm for this as part of a science project once.

You basically recursively divide the board into a bunch of overlapping 2x2 rects, testing the different possible combinations for winning on a 2x2 square.

It is slow, but it has the advantage of working on any sized board, with fairly linear memory requirements.

*I wish I could find my implementation*

Comment: Recursion for testing the finish is not necessary.