# Connect 4 Checking for a win algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I am making a connect 4 game, and I am trying to check for a win, so far I have been able to check right diagonally anywhere on the game board, How do I now check diagonally left, horizontally and vertically, I tried reversing the direction to check on diagonally left but that did not work? What can I change to check towards the left? horizontal and vertical

```
//Column Size
private static final int COLS = 7; 
//Row Size
private static final int ROWS = 6; 
//Dynamic Array
private State [][]count = new State[COLS][ROWS];
//Length of Pattern to check FOUR counters in a row
public static final int LEN=4;


//trajectory
public State checkWinner() {
    for(int col=0; col<count.length;++col) {
        for(int row=0; row<count[col].length; ++row) {
            State result = checkWinner(col,row);
            if (result!=null) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public State checkWinner(int col, int row) {
    State cell = count[col][row];
    if (cell==null ||cell==State.BLANK) { return null; }

    // check Diagonally Right 
    if((col+LEN<=COLS) && (row+LEN<=ROWS)){
        boolean same = true;
        for(int i=1;i<LEN;++i) {
            if (count[col+i][row+i]!=cell) {
                same=false;
                break;                  
            }
        }
        if (same) {
            return cell;
        }   
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You can take a look at: http://www.javaproblems.com/2013/01/creating-connect-four-game-in-java.html

Comment: I would have your winning method accept an offset for rows and offset for right. Then you check for runs using those offsets. Like if you call it with (-1, 1) then at each step it will check 1 column up and 1 row to the right.

Comment: what would the algorithm look like and what position is this for?

Comment: You may be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20202083/953482) post, where I describe the simplest possible win-checking algorithm ;-)

Comment: that is the worst possible way to check for a win

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect 4 check for a win algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770321/connect-4-check-for-a-win-algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend a much simpler approach. There are only a small number of possible winning patterns: 24 horizontally, 21 vertically, and 12 diagonally both ways for a total of 69 possibilities.

If you represent red and black as two separate bit fields, each has a total of 42 bits (present or not) which can be stored in an `int`. Create 69 bitmasks, one for each winning pattern, then AND each mask against the board position for red (or black) which is an int.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop in checkWinner(int col, int row) is only checking three positions; it should start at i = 0 rather than i = 1. To check vertically use count[col][row+i], to check horizontally use count[col+i][row]. Be sure to modify the if statement prior to the loop when checking in the reverse direction.

Comment: what do I modify it to? and what do you mean its only checking 3 positions? which one is the reverse direction? do you mean diagonally to the left?

Comment: It is connect four, so you need four matches correct? If the loop starts at 1 and goes to i<LEN, that is only i=1, i=2, i=3.

Comment: For your if statement prior to the loop on the reverse diagonal check, you could use if((col-LEN >=0) && (row-LEN>=0)). Then your loop would be for (i = LEN-1; i>=0; i--)

Comment: Instead try for(i=0; i<LEN; i++)...  count[col-i][row-i]  for the diagonal left and down. Use count[col-i][row

Comment: I'm assuming col 0 row 0 is the bottom left corner. After consideration you should only need to check the diagonals right up and right down. You have the right up case. For the loop use for(i=0; i<LEN; i++) for both. For right down use if ((col+LEN<=COLS)&&(row-LEN>=0))... count[col+i][row-i].

Comment: still does not reverse to the left

Comment: But you shouldn't need to check the reverse, just work left to right. And for verticals, bottom to top. And for the diagonals use what I described, that should cover all possible wins.

Comment: yeah that is working but its doing 5 in a row not 4, how do i change that?

Comment: Are you using for(i=o; i<LEN; i++)?