# How to properly checkDiagonalWin in connect 4

Tags: java

My check vertical win and check horizontal win work perfectly fine, however i dont know what to do with my check diagonal code to make it actually check diagonal. Some guidance would be much appreciated and this is in java. Thank you.

```
  private boolean checkVerticalWin() 
{
    PieceType type = myBoard[myLastPoint.x][myLastPoint.y];
    System.out.println("check vert");
    for(int j = 0; j < myNumColumns; j++)
    {   
    for(int i = 0; i < myNumRows; i++)
    {
        if(myBoard[i][j] == type && myBoard[i][j] != null )
        {
            count++;
            if(count == 1)
            {
                myWinBegin = new Point(i,j);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            myWinBegin = null;
            count = 0;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        if(count == myWinLength)
        {   
            myWinEnd = new Point(i,j);
            return true;
        }
    }
    }
    myWinBegin = null;
    return false;
}

private boolean checkHorizontalWin() 
{
    System.out.println("test");
    PieceType type = myBoard[myLastPoint.x][myLastPoint.y];
    for(int i = 0; i < myNumRows; i++)
    {
    for(int j = 0; j < myNumColumns; j++)
    {   
        if(myBoard[i][j] == type && myBoard[i][j] != null)
        {

            count++;
            if (count == 1)
            {
                myWinBegin = new Point(i,j);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            myWinBegin = null;
            count = 0;
        }
        if(count == myWinLength)
        {
            myWinEnd = new Point(i,j);
            return true;
        }
    }
    }
    myWinBegin = null;
    return false;
}

private boolean checkDiagonalWin() 
{
    PieceType type = myBoard[myLastPoint.x][myLastPoint.y];

    for(int i = 0; i < myNumRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < myNumColumns; j++)
        {
            if(myBoard[i][j] == type && myBoard[i][j] != null )
            {
                count++;
                myWinBegin = new Point(i,j);
            }
            else
            {
                count = 0;
                myWinEnd = new Point(i,j);
            }
            if(count == myWinLength)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < myNumColumns; j--)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < myNumRows; i--)
        {
            if(myBoard[i][j] == type && myBoard[i][j] != null )
            {
                count++;
                myWinBegin = new Point(i,j);
            }
            else
            {
                count = 0;
            }
            if(count == myWinLength)
            {
                myWinEnd = new Point(i,j);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < myNumColumns; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < myNumRows; i--)
        {
            if(myBoard[i][j] == type && myBoard[i][j] != null )
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                myWinBegin = new Point(i,j);
                count = 0;
            }
            if(count == myWinLength)
            {
                myWinEnd = new Point(i,j);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < myNumColumns; j--)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < myNumRows; i++)
        {
            if(myBoard[i][j] == type && myBoard[i][j] != null )
            {
                count++;
                myWinBegin = new Point(i,j);
            }
            else
            {
                count = 0;
            }
            if(count == myWinLength)
            {
                myWinEnd = new Point(i,j);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770321/connect-4-check-for-a-win-algorithm/32771401#32771401) way.  Basically, it has a start point (cell) and two delta values (row/column) which it then uses to check if the cells contain the same values (as the start cell).  This can be used to check in four diagonal directions (left/right, up/down) based on your needs

Comment: There is an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770321/connect-4-check-for-a-win-algorithm/38211417#38211417 I guess this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you need a start point, you then need to determine in which direction to move

With that idea in hand, you could use something like...

```
    boolean win = true;
    for (int count = 0; count < 4; count++) {
        if (row < myNumRows && row >= 0 && col < myNumColumns && col >= 0) {
            int test = myBoard[row][col];
            if (test != check) {
                win = false;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
        row += rowDelta;
        col += colDelta;
    }
```

As the basic algorithm.  All this does is checks each cell from a start point, to a total of 4 cells, the algorithm moves by the specified delta/direction and keeps checking while each cell matches the `check` value.

Now, I'd wrap this in a simple method

```
public boolean didWin(int[][] grid, int check, int row, int col, int rowDelta, int colDelta) {

    boolean win = true;
    for (int count = 0; count < 4; count++) {
        if (row < ROWS && row >= 0 && col < COLUMNS && col >= 0) {
            int test = grid[row][col];
            if (test != check) {
                win = false;
                break;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        row += rowDelta;
        col += colDelta;
    }
    return win;

}
```

which makes it simpler to call, know given any point, you can do something like...

```
int startRow = ...;
int startCol = ...;
int player = ...;

if (didWin(myBoard, player, startRow, startCol, 1, 0) || // Vertical, down
                didWin(myBoard, 1, startRow, startCol, 0, 1) || // Right
                didWin(myBoard, 1, startRow, startCol, 0, -1) || // Left
                didWin(myBoard, 1, startRow, startCol, 1, 1) || // Right/down
                didWin(myBoard, 1, startRow, startCol, -1, -1) || // Left/Up
                didWin(myBoard, 1, startRow, startCol, 1, -1) || // Down/Left
                didWin(myBoard, 1, startRow, startCol, -1, 1) // Up/Right
                ) {
    // You be the winner

}
```

*nb: I've left out check a vertical up direction, because it's unlikely that you could actually win this way*

*ps: I'd be even more lazy and would just have a `didWin` method, which did the above checks and returned `true` or `false`, but I'm lazy*

So, the `startRow` and `startCol` would represent the anchor point around which you want to check and would, in this example, represent the last drop.

This example uses a `int` to represent the player/token, but you could use anything, all this does is compares the token you supply with the values in the array