# TicTacToe win check doesn't work

Tags: java

I'm trying to get my TicTacToe working, but my win or lose checker doesn't work.

this is my startup frame.

```
package tictactoe;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TTT extends JFrame {


    public static void main( String args[] ) {
    JFrame frame = new TTT();

    frame.setSize( 695, 620 );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setTitle( "TicTacToe" );
    JPanel paneel = new paneel();
    frame.setContentPane( paneel );
    frame.setVisible( true );
    frame.setLocation( 400, 300 );
    }
}
```

and these are my buttons and panel.
    package tictactoe;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class paneel extends JPanel {


    private JButton start, exit, TTT1, TTT2, TTT3, TTT4, TTT5, TTT6, TTT7, TTT8, TTT9;
    private JTextField roundInt;

    static String x = "X";
    static String o = "O";

    static int round = 1; 
    static boolean playerTurn = true;

    public paneel() {
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    start = new JButton("Start");
    start.addActionListener(new startHandler());
    start.setBounds(100,100,400,100);
    start.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    start.setForeground(Color.black);
    start.setVisible(true);
    start.setOpaque(true);

    exit = new JButton("exit");
    exit.addActionListener(new exitHandler());
    exit.setBounds(100,300,400,100);
    exit.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    exit.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    exit.setVisible(true);
    exit.setOpaque(true);

    roundInt = new JTextField(round);
    roundInt.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    roundInt.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    roundInt.setBounds(590,20,70,40);
    roundInt.setVisible(false);

    TTT1 = new JButton();
    TTT2 = new JButton();
    TTT3 = new JButton();
    TTT4 = new JButton();
    TTT5 = new JButton();
    TTT6 = new JButton();
    TTT7 = new JButton();
    TTT8 = new JButton();
    TTT9 = new JButton();

    TTT1.addActionListener(new ttt1());
    TTT2.addActionListener(new ttt2());
    TTT3.addActionListener(new ttt3());
    TTT4.addActionListener(new ttt4());
    TTT5.addActionListener(new ttt5());
    TTT6.addActionListener(new ttt6());
    TTT7.addActionListener(new ttt7());
    TTT8.addActionListener(new ttt8());
    TTT9.addActionListener(new ttt9());

    TTT1.setBounds(20,20,170,170);
    TTT2.setBounds(200,20,170,170);
    TTT3.setBounds(380,20,170,170);
    TTT4.setBounds(20,200,170,170);
    TTT5.setBounds(200,200,170,170);
    TTT6.setBounds(380,200,170,170);
    TTT7.setBounds(20,380,170,170);
    TTT8.setBounds(200,380,170,170);
    TTT9.setBounds(380,380,170,170);

    TTT1.setBackground(Color.decode("0x999999"));
    TTT2.setBackground(Color.decode("0x999999"));
    TTT3.setBackground(Color.decode("0x999999"));
    TTT4.setBackground(Color.decode("0x999999"));
    TTT5.setBackground(Color.decode("0x999999"));
    TTT6.setBackground(Color.decode("0x999999"));
    TTT7.setBackground(Color.decode("0x999999"));
    TTT8.setBackground(Color.decode("0x999999"));
    TTT9.setBackground(Color.decode("0x999999"));


    TTT1.setVisible(false);
    TTT2.setVisible(false);
    TTT3.setVisible(false);
    TTT4.setVisible(false);
    TTT5.setVisible(false);
    TTT6.setVisible(false);
    TTT7.setVisible(false);
    TTT8.setVisible(false);
    TTT9.setVisible(false);

    TTT1.setForeground(Color.decode("0x000000"));
    TTT2.setForeground(Color.decode("0x000000"));
    TTT3.setForeground(Color.decode("0x000000"));
    TTT4.setForeground(Color.decode("0x000000"));
    TTT5.setForeground(Color.decode("0x000000"));
    TTT6.setForeground(Color.decode("0x000000"));
    TTT7.setForeground(Color.decode("0x000000"));
    TTT8.setForeground(Color.decode("0x000000"));
    TTT9.setForeground(Color.decode("0x000000"));

    add( start );
    add( exit );
    add( TTT1 );
    add( TTT2 );
    add( TTT3 );
    add( TTT4 );
    add( TTT5 );
    add( TTT6 );
    add( TTT7 );
    add( TTT8 );
    add( TTT9 );
    add( roundInt );
    }

    class exitHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
          System.exit(0);
        }
      }

    class startHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
          start.setVisible(false);
          exit.setVisible(false);
          roundInt.setVisible(true);

          TTT1.setVisible(true);
          TTT2.setVisible(true);
          TTT3.setVisible(true);
          TTT4.setVisible(true);
          TTT5.setVisible(true);
          TTT6.setVisible(true);
          TTT7.setVisible(true);
          TTT8.setVisible(true);
          TTT9.setVisible(true);
        }
      }

    class ttt1 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            if(playerTurn){
                TTT1.setText("X");
                playerTurn = false;
                wincheck.knop1C = 1;
                round++;
              }else{
                TTT1.setText("O");
                playerTurn = true;
                wincheck.knop1C = 2;
                round++;
              }
        }
      }

    class ttt2 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            if(playerTurn){
                TTT2.setText("X");
                playerTurn = false;
                wincheck.knop2C = 1;
                round++;
              }else{
                TTT2.setText("O");
                playerTurn = true;
                wincheck.knop2C = 2;
                round++;
              }
        }
      }

    class ttt3 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            if(playerTurn){
                TTT3.setText("X");
                playerTurn = false;
                wincheck.knop3C = 1;
                round++;
              }else{
                TTT3.setText("O");
                playerTurn = true;
                wincheck.knop3C = 2;
                round++;
              }
        }
      }

    class ttt4 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            if(playerTurn){
                TTT4.setText("X");
                playerTurn = false;
                wincheck.knop4C = 1;
                round++;
              }else{
                TTT4.setText("O");
                playerTurn = true;
                wincheck.knop4C = 2;
                round++;
              }
        }
      }

    class ttt5 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            if(playerTurn){
                TTT5.setText("X");
                playerTurn = false;
                wincheck.knop5C = 1;
                round++;
              }else{
                TTT5.setText("O");
                playerTurn = true;
                wincheck.knop5C = 2;
                round++;
              }
        }
      }

    class ttt6 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            if(playerTurn){
                TTT6.setText("X");
                playerTurn = false;
                wincheck.knop6C = 1;
                round++;
              }else{
                TTT6.setText("O");
                playerTurn = true;
                wincheck.knop6C = 2;
                round++;
              }
        }
      }

    class ttt7 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            if(playerTurn){
                TTT7.setText("X");
                playerTurn = false;
                wincheck.knop7C = 1;
                round++;
              }else{
                TTT7.setText("O");
                playerTurn = true;
                wincheck.knop7C = 2;
                round++;
              }
        }
      }

    class ttt8 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            if(playerTurn){
                TTT8.setText("X");
                playerTurn = false;
                wincheck.knop8C = 1;
                round++;
              }else{
                TTT8.setText("O");
                playerTurn = true;
                wincheck.knop8C = 2;
                round++;
              }
        }
      }

    class ttt9 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            if(playerTurn){
                TTT9.setText("X");
                playerTurn = false;
                wincheck.knop9C = 1;
                round++;
              }else{
                TTT9.setText("O");
                playerTurn = true;
                wincheck.knop9C = 2;
                round++;
              }
        }
      }
}
```

and this is my Win or lose checker.

```
package tictactoe;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class wincheck {
    static int knop1C;
    static int knop2C;
    static int knop3C;
    static int knop4C;
    static int knop5C;
    static int knop6C;
    static int knop7C;
    static int knop8C;
    static int knop9C;

    public static void checkWin(){
        if(knop1C == 1 && knop2C == 1 && knop3C == 1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "player 1 wins!");
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(knop4C == 1 && knop5C == 1 && knop6C == 1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "player 1 wins!");
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(knop7C == 1 && knop8C == 1 && knop9C == 1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "player 1 wins!");
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(knop1C == 1 && knop5C == 1 && knop9C == 1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "player 1 wins!");
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(knop3C == 1 && knop5C == 1 && knop7C == 1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "player 1 wins!");
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(knop1C == 1 && knop4C == 1 && knop7C == 1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "player 1 wins!");
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(knop2C == 1 && knop5C == 1 && knop8C == 1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "player 1 wins!");
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(knop3C == 1 && knop6C == 1 && knop9C == 1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "player 1 wins!");
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(knop1C == 2 && knop2C == 2 && knop3C == 2){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "player 2 wins!");
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(knop4C == 2 && knop5C == 2 && knop6C == 2){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "player 2 wins!");
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(knop7C == 2 && knop8C == 2 && knop9C == 2){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "player 2 wins!");
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(knop1C == 2 && knop5C == 2 && knop9C == 2){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "player 2 wins!");
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(knop3C == 2 && knop5C == 2 && knop7C == 2){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "player 2 wins!");
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(knop1C == 2 && knop4C == 2 && knop7C == 2){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "player 2 wins!");
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(knop2C == 2 && knop5C == 2 && knop8C == 2){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "player 2 wins!");
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(knop3C == 2 && knop6C == 2 && knop9C == 2){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "player 2 wins!");
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(round > 9){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Draw");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help? I need this for a school project.

(by the way, I'm dutch. Please don't mind my bad grammar)

Comment: It looks like you never actually call `checkWin`.

Comment: 1. Learn about arrays and then use them. By doing this you could eliminate 90% of all that unnecessarily redundant code above making your program much easier to change and to debug. 2. Your wincheck uses its own variables, none of which are related in any way to the GUi variables. 3. Better to create an OOP-compliant model class that does the win checking and that the GUI (or view) can use.

Comment: @resueman: even if he did, it would do nothing of use.

Comment: I'd advise learning about debugging. If you are using Eclipse for example you can use "Debug" to walk through your program step by step. You can then see when variables are changed in real time to isolate your problem. But yes it looks like Resueman is correct, you created the class but never called it. Kudos him for reading through all that :)

Comment: @resueman where should i call it in then? in really a beginner sorry!

Comment: Going along with what @HovercraftFullOfEels said, there is no reason to have a separate class for each square and certainly no need to have each of them implementing `ActionListener`. The same listener can be used for all squares and identify the source of the event and execute code accordingly

Comment: @MennoSpijker Trying adding it to the end of your `actionPerformed` methods. If it still doesn't work, then do some debugging inside that method to figure out what the values are, vs what you expect. (also do what Hovercraft Full Of Eels says; it'll make your code much easier to manage).

Comment: Also check the [many similar questions that can be found on this site](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java+swing+tic+tac+toe+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F) including [these check for win questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java+swing+tic+tac+toe+win+check+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F).

Comment: A [conceptual idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960625/how-to-properly-checkdiagonalwin-in-connect-4/32961044#32961044) and [conceptual idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788054/need-better-logic-for-tictactoe/29788374#29788374)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not going to do your work for you, but I am going to show you how to try to simplify it immensely by using arrays, layout managers, and a single ActionListener to replace 90% of your excessive code. Please note comments in the code:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TicTacToePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int SIDES = 3;
    private static final Font FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 60);

    // 2D array of all buttons
    private JButton[][] grid = new JButton[SIDES][SIDES];

    public TicTacToePanel() {
        // use a single ActionListener for all buttons
        ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();

        // use a GridLayout to easily create your 3x3 grid
        setLayout(new GridLayout(SIDES, SIDES));

        // use a nested for loop to create your "grid" of
        // JButtons. 
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < grid[row].length; column++) {

                // create your button, and its properties
                JButton btn = new JButton("   "); // give it some width
                btn.setFont(FONT); // make button bigger by using large Font

                // add an ActionListener to it
                btn.addActionListener(listener);

                // add it to the GUI -- the current JPanel
                add(btn);

                // place it in the 2D grid array of JButton
                grid[row][column] = btn;
            }
        }
    }

    // single listener for all buttons
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // get which button was pushed
            JButton sourceButton = (JButton) e.getSource();

            // Now use nested for loops to find row and column button pressed

            // change text in that button if not already set

            // check for win here. Since you know the row and column of the 
            // last button pressed
            // you can search for win associated with the row, column, and possibly
            // diagonal that involves just that button. No need to look at all possible
            // wins.

        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new TicTacToePanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```