# Tic-Tac-Toe to check for a winner

Tags: java, eclipse

I have complied a tic-tac-toe game but my only issue is that I cannot determine a winner/tie from the game. I have a method specifically for finding the winner but it isn't working. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe {

    public static final int X = 1;
    public static final int Y = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int X = 1;
        final int Y = 2;

        int[][] board = {{0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0}
        };

        int count = 0;

        while (!checkWinner(board)) {
            printBoard(board);

            if (count % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("X's turn");
                move(X, board);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Y's turn");
                move(Y, board);
            }

            System.out.println();
            count++;
        }

    }

    public static boolean checkWinner(int[][] board) {
        if (board[0][0] == board[1][0] && board[1][0] == board[2][0] && (board[0][0] == "X" || board[0][0] == "Y")) {
            return true;
        } else if (board[0][1] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][1] && (board[0][1] == "X" || board[0][1] == "Y")) {
            return true;
        } else if (board[0][2] == board[1][2] && board[1][2] == board[2][2] && (board[0][2] == "X" || board[0][2] == "Y")) {
            return true;
        } else if (board[0][0] == board[0][1] && board[0][1] == board[0][2] && (board[0][0] == "X" || board[0][0] == "Y")) {
            return true;
        } else if (board[1][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[1][2] && (board[1][0] == "X" || board[1][0] == "Y")) {
            return true;
        } else if (board[2][0] == board[2][1] && board[2][1] == board[2][2] && (board[2][0] == "X" || board[2][0] == "Y")) {
            return true;
        } else if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2] && (board[0][0] == "X" || board[0][0] == "Y")) {
            return true;
        } else if (board[2][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[0][2] && (board[2][0] == "X" || board[2][0] == "Y")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void printBoard(int[][] board) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.print("| ");
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] == TicTacToe.X) {
                    System.out.print("X");
                } else if (board[i][j] == TicTacToe.Y) {
                    System.out.print("Y");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("-");
                }
                System.out.print(" | ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void move(int player, int[][] board) {
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Row: ");
        int x = myScan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Column: ");
        int y = myScan.nextInt();

        board[x][y] = player;

    }

}
```

I don't need to add another method to this program, as this is all I need.

Comment: Basically, you have a 3x3 matrix, so given a single start point, you need to check for horizontal, vertical and diagonal directions, the good news is, the start point can always be the first row (and check down), maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960625/how-to-properly-checkdiagonalwin-in-connect-4/32961044#32961044) and something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770321/connect-4-check-for-a-win-algorithm/32771401#32771401)

Answer (score 3):

You should replace the condition in the `while` loop to, if no winner **AND** *board is not full*:

```
while(!checkWinner(board) && /*board is not full*/) {
//...
}

if(checkWinner(board)) //→ there's a winner;
else //it's a draw;
```

I suggest that you revisit the `checkWinner` method, although that format works, it's quite inefficient and you could find a simpler and more fun way to implement it. For example, you could exploit something like:

```
int n = board[0][0] * board[0][1] * board[0][2];
n == 0; → has vacant cells
n == 1; → player 1 won
n == 8; → player 2 won
```

Comment: even more efficent. just for fun. `int n = board[0][0] & board[0][1] & board[0][2];` Then  `n == 0` no winner, `n==1` player one wins, `n==2` player 2 wins. I dont recommend this in general as explicit coding is good coding, and only optimize where optimization is needed -- but its a good challenge for a starting coder to figure out why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Is your code compiling without any errors ?

I don't see how this could work ?
    board[1][0] == "X"

board is an array of integers ! You should see "Incompatible operand types int and String" !

Comment: I changed it from "X" to 'X'.

Comment: That's wrong too... 'x' (with single quotes) would be interpreted as byte not String.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is of type integer but you compare it in your function with strings like "X" and  "Y". You have to replace  ... == " X" with ... == TicTacToe.X  and ... == "Y" with ... == TicTacToe.Y in all your  if statements in your checkWinner() function.