# Random Tic Tac Toe checker issue

Tags: java

Alright so I have to make a random tictactoe checker that shows when x wins, when o wins, and when there is a tie. So the issues I'm having is it wont show the ties and it will sometimes say that either x or o won when they didn't. I don't know what to change around in my code because before I did my diagonal check it would print out the ties. Here is the whole code but I'm pretty sure the problem is coming from the checking board part by making xWin and oWin come out true I can't find where its doing that tho.

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class TicTacToe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to random Tic Tac Toe Checker. Let's see our randomly generated board.");
        int dimension = 3;
        char[][] board = new char[dimension][dimension];
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // filling board
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                int choice = r.nextInt(2);
                if (choice == 0) {
                    board[i][j] = 'X';
                } else if (choice == 1) {
                    board[i][j] = 'O';
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // filling board
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.print(board[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        boolean xWin = false;// checking board, order horizontal,vertical,left
                                // and right diagonal
        boolean oWin = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            boolean lineWin = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] != board[i][0]) {
                    lineWin = false;

                }
            }
            if (lineWin == true) {
                if (board[i][0] == 'X') {
                    xWin = false;
                }
                if (board[i][0] == 'O') {
                    oWin = false;
                }

            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            boolean lineWin = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                if (board[i][j] != board[0][j]) {
                    lineWin = true;

                }
            }
            if (lineWin == true) {
                if (board[0][j] == 'X') {
                    xWin = true;
                }
                if (board[0][j] == 'O') {
                    oWin = true;
                }

            }
        }
        boolean lineWin = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (board[0][0] != board[i][i]) {
                lineWin = false;
            }
            if (lineWin == true) {
                if (board[0][0] == 'X') {
                    xWin = true;
                }
                if (board[0][0] == 'O') {
                    oWin = true;
                }

            }
        }
        lineWin = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (board[0][0] != board[i][2 - i]) {
                lineWin = false;
            }
            if (lineWin == true) {
                if (board[0][0] == 'X') {
                    xWin = true;
                }
                if (board[0][0] == 'O') {
                    oWin = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (xWin == false && oWin == false)// printing winners
        {
            System.out.println("CAT!It's a tie no one wins");
        }
        if (xWin == true) {
            System.out.println("X wins!");
        }

        if (oWin == true) {
            System.out.println("O wins!");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Consider this, if you know a `line` can no longer be won, why would you continue checking it?  Also, if you know `X` or `O` has already won, why would you continue checking for other possible win conditions? Something like [Branching Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) (in particular the `break` statement) might help

Comment: Could you please give an example for which your implementation fails?

Comment: `if(board[0][0] != board[i][2-i])` in your last check is wrong, it's not `[0][0]` but `[0][2]`

Comment: @Codor
XOX
OXX
OXX
X wins!
O wins!                                                                                                      XOO
XXX
OXX
X wins!
O wins!

Comment: @MadProgrammer my problem is I don't know where it continues to keep checking and I just tried what you recommended and I'm pretty sure I did it wrong. I've been overthinking this way to much now everything I have been trying just doesn't work.

Comment: @themannn This is just my opinion, but you've over complicated the issue.  The basic idea is, you want to check for a win condition by starting at a particular cell and moving in a particular direction (x/y), this is basically demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770321/connect-4-check-for-a-win-algorithm/32771401#32771401), while it seems more complex, the basic alogrthim is very simple and reusable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the boolean errors as well as the diagonal logic:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class TicTacToe {
  private static final int DIMENSION = 3;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to random Tic Tac Toe Checker. Let's see our randomly generated board.");
    char[][] board = new char[DIMENSION][DIMENSION];
    final Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < DIMENSION; j++) {
        int choice = r.nextInt(2);
        if (choice == 0) {
          board[i][j] = 'X';
        } else if (choice == 1) {
          board[i][j] = 'O';
        }
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < DIMENSION; j++) {
        System.out.print(board[i][j]);
      }
      System.out.println();
    }


    boolean xWin = false;
    boolean oWin = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++) {
      boolean lineWin = true;
      for (int j = 0; j < DIMENSION; j++) {
        if (board[i][j] != board[i][0]) {
          lineWin = false;
        }
      }
      if (lineWin) {
        if (board[i][0] == 'X') {
          xWin = true;
        }
        if (board[i][0] == 'O') {
          oWin = true;
        }

      }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < DIMENSION; j++) {
      boolean lineWin = true;
      for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++) {
        if (board[i][j] != board[0][j]) {
          lineWin = false;
        }
      }
      if (lineWin) {
        if (board[0][j] == 'X') {
          xWin = true;
        }
        if (board[0][j] == 'O') {
          oWin = true;
        }

      }
    }
    boolean lineWin = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++) {
      if (board[0][0] != board[i][i]) {
        lineWin = false;
      }
    }
    if (lineWin) {//this check should not be in the loop
      if (board[0][0] == 'X') {
        xWin = true;
      }
      if (board[0][0] == 'O') {
        oWin = true;
      }

    }
    lineWin = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++) {
      if (board[DIMENSION - 1][0] != board[i][DIMENSION - 1 - i]) {
        lineWin = false;
      }
    }
    if (lineWin) {//this check should not be in the loop
      if (board[DIMENSION - 1][0] == 'X') {
        xWin = true;
      }
      if (board[DIMENSION - 1][0] == 'O') {
        oWin = true;
      }
    }
    if (xWin == true && oWin == true) {//printing winners
      System.out.println("Both players won!");
    }
    if (xWin == false && oWin == false) {
      System.out.println("CAT!It's a tie no one wins");
    }
    if (xWin == true) {
      System.out.println("X wins!");
    }

    if (oWin == true) {
      System.out.println("O wins!");
    }
  }
}
```

Note: you can increase DIMENSION for a laugh.

Comment: Your a god among men

Answer (score 0):

In the first block

```
if(lineWin == true)
{
  if(board[i][0] == 'X')
  {
    xWin = false;
  }
  if(board[i][0] == 'O')
  {
    oWin = false;
  }
}
```

should be changed as follows.

```
if(lineWin == true)
{
  if(board[i][0] == 'X')
  {
    xWin = true;
  }
  if(board[i][0] == 'O')
  {
    oWin = true;
  }
}
```

Furthermore, in the second block, the part

```
if(board[i][j] != board[0][j])
{
  lineWin = true;
}
```

should be changed as follows.

```
if(board[i][j] != board[0][j])
{
  lineWin = false;
}
```

Comment: Tried that and it is still printing that won is winning when it isnt and still isnt recording the ties

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem in this file comes around the middle, specifically lines 34 - 66, where you do the initial checks for horizontal and vertical rows of the same character.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        boolean lineWin = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] != board[i][0]) {
                lineWin = false;

            }
        }
        if (lineWin == true) {
            if (board[i][0] == 'X') {
                xWin = false; //THESE LINES SHOULD BE CHANGING THE WIN CONDITION TO TRUE
            }
            if (board[i][0] == 'O') {
                oWin = false; //LISTED ABOVE
            }

        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        boolean lineWin = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (board[i][j] != board[0][j]) {
                lineWin = true; //THIS LINE SHOULD BE FALSE

            }
        }
        if (lineWin == true) {
            if (board[0][j] == 'X') {
                xWin = true;
            }
            if (board[0][j] == 'O') {
                oWin = true;
            }
        }
```

I listed some changes that will fix the code and make it run the way you want it to. It looks like there were some errors in declaring a boolean to be `true` or `false` at the wrong time, so this should be able to fix the problem.

Comment: I tried the changes and it still isn't printing the ties and is printing that one has won when it hasnt