# TicTacToe Swing game not detecting winner

Tags: java, swing

Program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TicTacToe implements ActionListener {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
    JButton b[] = new JButton[9];

    String letter = "";
    ImageIcon X;
    ImageIcon O;
    ImageIcon ltr;
    int value = 0;
    boolean win = false;

    public TicTacToe() {
        // Assign images
        X = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("X.png"));
        O = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("O.png"));
        // Create the Window
        window.setSize(500,500);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

        // Add Buttons
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            b[i] = new JButton();
            window.add(b[i]);
        }

        // Add ActionListener
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            b[i].addActionListener(this);
        }

        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        value++;
        // Who's Turn
        if (value % 2 == 1) {
            ltr = X;
            letter = "X";
        }
        if (value % 2 == 0) {
            ltr = O;
            letter = "O";
        }

        String[] letters = new String[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            letters[i] = "";
        }

        // Display Letters
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (a.getSource() == b[i]) {
                b[i].setIcon(ltr);
                b[i].setDisabledIcon(ltr);
                b[i].setEnabled(false);
                letters[i] = letter;
                // Check what is printing
                System.out.println(i + letters[i]);
            }
        }

        // Who Won

        // Horizontal
        if (letters[0].equals(letters[1]) && letters[1].equals(letters[2]) && !letters[0].equals("")) {
            win = true;
        } else if (letters[3].equals(letters[4]) && letters[4].equals(letters[5]) && !letters[3].equals("")) {
            win = true;
        } else if (letters[6].equals(letters[7]) && letters[7].equals(letters[8]) && !letters[6].equals("")) {
            win = true;
        }

        // Vertical
        if (letters[0].equals(letters[3]) && letters[3].equals(letters[6]) && !letters[0].equals("")) {
            win = true;
        } else if (letters[1].equals(letters[4]) && letters[4].equals(letters[7]) && !letters[1].equals("")) {
            win = true;
        } else if (letters[2].equals(letters[5]) && letters[5].equals(letters[8]) && !letters[2].equals("")) {
            win = true;
        }

        // Diagonal
        if (letters[0].equals(letters[4]) && letters[4].equals(letters[8]) && !letters[0].equals("")) {
            win = true;
        } else if (letters[2].equals(letters[4]) && letters[4].equals(letters[6]) && !letters[2].equals("")) {
            win = true;
        }

        if (win) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player " + letter + " wins!");
            for (JButton i : b) {
                i.setEnabled(false);
            }
        } else if (!win && value == 9) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The game ended in a tie.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TicTacToe();
    }
}
```

I originally had it display letters, but I wanted it to display images. In order for it to check, I made a String array. I displayed the icons in the for loop, while also adding the letters to the string array, so I could compare them.

It's not detecting a winner when it should, so it looks like `win` isn't becoming true. It's detecting when all the buttons are pressed.

```
System.out.println(i + letters[i]);
```

is supposed to check what the values are, and I get

```
0X
1O
2X
3O
4X
5O
6X
7O
8X
```

so obviously the letters are in the array. The if conditions aren't comparing properly. Any help, please?

Comment: While [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770321/connect-4-check-for-a-win-algorithm/32771401#32771401) is for connect four, the basic idea is the same

Comment: Did you step through your code in the debugger to see what the values are and how the conditions are  being evaluated?  Please do at least that before posting.

Comment: You are initializing your `letters` array on every `actionPerformed`. So for every click there is only actually one value in the array. Try moving your array to class scope

Comment: @JavaDevil That should be an answer, not a comment.  I was about to post an answer but since you got it first I'll let you do it.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yeah I thought so but it just seems like it was to simple that it didn't deserve a full answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing your `letters` array on every `actionPerformed`.

```
String[] letters = new String[9];
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    letters[i] = "";
}
```

So for every click there is only actually one value in the array and you are only printing the current turn selection which gives you the illusion that you have stored the moves.

To verify this you could try adding

```
System.out.println("Current moves: " + Arrays.toString(letters));
```

And you will see the problem more visually.

To fix this yry moving your array to be class scope and you can initialise it in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

you aren't storing `letters`, so everytime you click on a button, the array contains `""` in every cells except the one you clicked.

To avoid this problem, you could just set `letters` as a property of your class and initialize it with `""` in the constructor. It would look like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TicTacToe implements ActionListener {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
    JButton b[] = new JButton[9];

    String[] letters = new String[9];
    String letter = "";
    ImageIcon X;
    ImageIcon O;
    ImageIcon ltr;
    int value = 0;
    boolean win = false;

    public TicTacToe() {
        // Assign images
        X = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("X.png"));
        O = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("O.png"));
        // Create the Window
        window.setSize(500,500);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

        // Initialize letters
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            letters[i] = "";
        }

        // Add Buttons
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            b[i] = new JButton();
            window.add(b[i]);
        }

        // Add ActionListener
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            b[i].addActionListener(this);
        }

        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        value++;
        // Who's Turn
        if (value % 2 == 1) {
            ltr = X;
            letter = "X";
        }
        if (value % 2 == 0) {
            ltr = O;
            letter = "O";
        }

        // Display Letters
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (a.getSource() == b[i]) {
                b[i].setIcon(ltr);
                b[i].setDisabledIcon(ltr);
                b[i].setEnabled(false);
                letters[i] = letter;
                // Check what is printing
                System.out.println(i + letters[i]);
            }
        }

        // Who Won

        // Horizontal
        if (letters[0].equals(letters[1]) && letters[1].equals(letters[2]) && !letters[0].equals("")) {
            win = true;
        } else if (letters[3].equals(letters[4]) && letters[4].equals(letters[5]) && !letters[3].equals("")) {
            win = true;
        } else if (letters[6].equals(letters[7]) && letters[7].equals(letters[8]) && !letters[6].equals("")) {
            win = true;
        }

        // Vertical
        if (letters[0].equals(letters[3]) && letters[3].equals(letters[6]) && !letters[0].equals("")) {
            win = true;
        } else if (letters[1].equals(letters[4]) && letters[4].equals(letters[7]) && !letters[1].equals("")) {
            win = true;
        } else if (letters[2].equals(letters[5]) && letters[5].equals(letters[8]) && !letters[2].equals("")) {
            win = true;
        }

        // Diagonal
        if (letters[0].equals(letters[4]) && letters[4].equals(letters[8]) && !letters[0].equals("")) {
            win = true;
        } else if (letters[2].equals(letters[4]) && letters[4].equals(letters[6]) && !letters[2].equals("")) {
            win = true;
        }

        if (win) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player " + letter + " wins!");
            for (JButton i : b) {
                i.setEnabled(false);
            }
        } else if (!win && value == 9) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The game ended in a tie.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TicTacToe();
    }
}
```