# Detecting combinations in the 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Can anybody point me in the right direction?
I am trying to come up with an algorithm which checks if there are 3 same values in a row, column or diagonally. all elements of the array should be tested for this. Also, the 2d array size can be from 1 to 10. I've tried various implementation but they dont test it properly.

For instance, XXX is found when the first element is tested but if the middle element is tested then it doesn't flag up

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Out of interest, is this an attempt at noughts-and-crosses in Java with a larger board?

Comment: Not only is this a "please solve my homework for me question", it's one which has been [answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100917/connect-four-game-in-java) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770321/connect-4-check-for-a-win-algorithm) [times](http://www.javaproblems.com/2013/01/creating-connect-four-game-in-java.html) here and elsewhere eon the internet.

Comment: "I've tried various implementation but they dont test it properly." Then you need to spend time on a debugger to find the problem.  Voting to close due to lack of perceived effort.

Comment: Yes something like that

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm**:

```
Loop through every row in the 2d List:
  Loop through every element of the row:

    Check if the element is the first one of its row:
      If yes, check if the next two are the same as this one. If yes, you've found a match.
    Else check if the element is the last one of its row:
      If yes, check if the previous two are the same as this one. If yes, you've found a match.
    Else:
      Check if the previous and next ones are the same as this one. If yes, you've found a match.

    If it's not a match:
      Check if the element is in the first row:
          If yes, check if the two below are the same as this one. If yes, you've found a match.
      Else check if the element is in the last row:
          If yes, check if the two above are the same as this one. If yes, you've found a match.
      Else:
          Check if the above and below ones are the same as this one. If yes, you've found a match.
```