# Connect4 winning algorithm in a given format

Tags: java, algorithm

Let us say the status of a Connect4 game is stored like `12341`, which means player 1 dropped his ball in position 1, and then player 2 in position 2, player 1 in position 3, player 2 in position 4 and player 1 in position 1 again.

In this format, is there an algorithm that can know if a game is won, in a way that is better than converting into a 2-d matrix and using the algorithms that is already listed in SO, like [Connect 4 check for a win algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770321/connect-4-check-for-a-win-algorithm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristics of the game connectivity are such that the most effective method is to convert to the 2D paradigm to check for wins.  The fastest method for most people is to check the current move in all directions, to see whether it just created a win.

You *can* somewhat improve the "intelligence" of the checking, by keeping a list of "live" lines -- possible future wins -- and checking to see which ones the most recent move extends or blocks.

Note that this is a less obvious approach for both coding and maintenance.  Also, it's *slower* than checking the current move in all directions.  It's really useful only if used to create an automatic player (AI).