# How could I do my winning function for connect 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to do my winning functions for connect 4 and am getting kind of stumped, everything I have tried hasn't worked yet. I am doing this for a class project so I really want to learn how to do this, I think I have just been coding so much this week my brain is fried. Any suggestions are appreciated thank you!

```js
const noPlayer = 0; //no player
let currentPlayer = 1; //default player

const numRows = 7; //rows
const numCols = numRows; //columns
const board = Array.from(Array(numCols), (column) => Array(numRows).fill(0)); //board array

function playerChange() {
  //player change function
  currentPlayer = -currentPlayer;
}

const playerClasses = {
  //taken/open space classes
  [-1]: `tree`, //tree
  [noPlayer]: `none`, //no player
  [1]: `deer`, //deer
};

function drawBoard() {
  //creating board
  const $container = $(".container");
  $container.html("");
  for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numRows; rowIndex++) {
    board.forEach((column, columnIndex) => {
      const playerId = column[rowIndex];
      const playerClass = playerClasses[playerId];
      $container.append(
        //appends all data to container
        `<div data-row="${rowIndex}" data-col="${columnIndex}" class="cell ${playerClass}"></div>`
      );
    });
  }
}
drawBoard();

$("button").on("click", function () {
  location.reload();
});

$(".container").on("click", ".cell", function (clicky) {
  const targetRow = $(clicky.currentTarget).data("row");
  const targetCol = $(clicky.currentTarget).data("col");
  const currentVal = board[targetCol][targetRow];
  if (currentVal !== noPlayer) {
    return;
  }
  const takenRow = board[targetCol].findIndex((none) => none !== noPlayer);
  const lowestRow = takenRow === -1 ? numRows - 1 : takenRow - 1;
  board[targetCol][lowestRow] = currentPlayer;
  drawBoard();
  playerChange();
});

//WRITE WINNING CONDITIONS DOWN HERE
```

```css
/*general page styling*/
body {
  background-image: url("https://images.hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/minimalist-landscape-to.jpg");
  font-family: "Amatic SC", cursive;
}

/*page heading styling*/
h1 {
  font-size: 75px;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #412846;
  color: white;
}

/*help with centering*/
section {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/*styling for button*/
button {
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  background-color: rgb(78, 29, 214);
  font-family: "Amatic SC", cursive;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgb(24, 0, 70);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px 0 rgb(24, 0, 70);
  outline: none;
}

/*styling for button hover*/
button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px 0 rgb(24, 0, 70);
  background-color: rgb(192, 128, 252);
  color: rgb(24, 0, 70);
}

/*styling for footer*/
footer {
  font-size: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  color: rgb(218, 198, 255);
  padding-top: 15px;
}

/*styling for connect 4 board*/
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, auto);
  width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

/*styling for individual cells on board*/
.cell {
  font-family: "Major Mono Display", monospace;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(218, 198, 255);
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(24, 0, 70);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  background-position: center;
}

.cell.deer {
  background-image: url("https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/reindeer-black-antlers-png-picture-8.png");
}
.cell.tree {
  background-image: url("https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/24-242635_white-pine-tree-clipart-clipart-free-pine-tree.png");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC:wght@400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC:wght@400;700&family=Major+Mono+Display&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script defer src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <title>c o n n e c t 4</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <!--PAGE HEADING-->
      <h1>C O N N E C T 4</h1>
      <!--CONNECT 4 GAME BOARD-->
      <!--class cell for general-->
      <div class="container"></div>
      <!--RESTART GAME BUTTON-->
      <button>Restart Game</button>
      <!--PAGE FOOTER-->
      <footer>Made by Falon B. Landers</footer>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: One way would be to write a loop which iterates through every filled cell and recursively checks the neighbouring cells filled by the same player to see if their length meets  winning requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are an example of how this can be done:

results are a list of `[index, direction]`

```js
let map = [
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 0,-1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1,-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
   -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,-1,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,-1,
   -1,-1,-1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
] 
// how many column do we have:
let col = 9
// we dont need all directions!
let movingDirections = [1, col, col+1, col-1]

function checkWinning(sign){
    let wins = []
    for (let index = 0; index< map.length; index++){
       if(map[index]===sign){ // on a correct sign!
         let found = checkAllDirection(sign, index) 
         if(found){
            wins.push(found)
         }
       }      
    }
    
    return wins;
}
function checkAllDirection(sign, index){
   for(let q=0; q< movingDirections.length; q++){
      let dir = movingDirections[q];
      let found = checkDirection(sign, index, dir)
      if(found){
         // if found we return index and the direction
         return [index, dir]
      }
   }
}
function checkDirection(sign, index, dir){
    let oldIndex = index
    for(let x=1; x<4; x++){// four of them?
      let nextIndex = index + dir * x;
      if(!testDir(dir, oldIndex, nextIndex)){
         //new line - not correct!
         return false;
      }
      if(map[nextIndex] !== sign){
         // not correct sign
         return false;
      }
      oldIndex = nextIndex;
    }
    return true;
}
function row(index){
   return Math.floor(index/col) 
}
function column(index){
   return index%col
}


function testDir(dir, index1, index2){
  let row1 = row(index1) 
  let row2 = row(index2) 
  let col1 = column(index1) 
  let col2 = column(index2)
  if(dir === 1){
    return row2 === row1 && col2 === col1+1;
  }
  if(dir === col){
    return row2 === row1+1 && col2 === col1;
  }
  if(dir === col+1){
    return row2 == row1+1 && col2 === col1+1;
  }
  if(dir === col-1){
    return row2 == row1+1 && col2 === col1-1;
  }
}


let test1 = checkWinning(1)
console.log(`Test for 1 found: ([index, direction])`)
console.log(test1)
let test2 = checkWinning(-1)
console.log(`Test for -1 found:`)
console.log(test2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770321/connect-4-check-for-a-win-algorithm) post!
I wanted to comment, instead of make an answer for this, but I don't have enough reputation yet. I hope it helps you.