# TicTacToe game won't paint winning move and board won't reset after new game is started?

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on making a tic tac toe game in Java, and when you place a winning move the winning move won't actually get painted. Also, when you try to play another round, the new game button won't reset the board and clear all the previously painted x's and o's. Any ideas would be appreciated, as I've been working on just trying to finish this for hours, and I haven't gotten anywhere.

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TTTGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TicTacToe();
    }
}

class TicTacToe extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel northpanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel centerpanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel eastborder = new JPanel();
    JPanel westborder = new JPanel();
    JPanel southborder = new JPanel();
    JButton newgame = new JButton();
    JLabel turn = new JLabel();
    JLabel score = new JLabel();
    boolean xturn;
    boolean live = false;
    Square s1 = new Square();
    Square s2 = new Square();
    Square s3 = new Square();
    Square s4 = new Square();
    Square s5 = new Square();
    Square s6 = new Square();
    Square s7 = new Square();
    Square s8 = new Square();
    Square s9 = new Square();
    HashMap<Square,Integer> indices = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Integer,Character> states = new HashMap<>();
    JLabel xwins = new JLabel();
    JLabel owins = new JLabel();
    JLabel draws = new JLabel();
    int oScore = 0;
    int xScore = 0;
    int drawScore = 0;

    public TicTacToe() {

        this.frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.frame.add(northpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.frame.add(centerpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.frame.add(eastborder, BorderLayout.EAST);
        this.frame.add(westborder, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.frame.add(southborder, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.frame.setVisible(true);
        this.frame.setSize(500, 500);
        this.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.frame.setTitle("TicTacToe");

        this.northpanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        this.northpanel.setVisible(true);
        this.northpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        this.northpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
        this.northpanel.add(newgame);
        this.northpanel.add(turn);
        this.northpanel.add(score);

        this.centerpanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        this.centerpanel.setVisible(true);
        this.centerpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

        this.eastborder.setVisible(true);
        this.eastborder.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.eastborder.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1,100));

        this.westborder.setVisible(true);
        this.westborder.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.westborder.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1,100));

        this.southborder.setVisible(true);
        this.southborder.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.southborder.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,1));

        this.newgame.addActionListener(this);
        this.newgame.setVisible(true);
        this.newgame.setText("New Game");
        this.newgame.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.ITALIC,20));
        this.newgame.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        this.newgame.setFocusable(false);
        this.newgame.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        this.newgame.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        this.newgame.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        this.turn.setVisible(true);
        this.turn.setOpaque(true);
        this.turn.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        this.turn.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        this.turn.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.ITALIC,20));
        this.turn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        this.turn.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        this.score.setVisible(true);
        this.score.setOpaque(true);
        this.score.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        this.score.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        this.score.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        this.score.add(xwins);
        this.score.add(owins);
        this.score.add(draws);

        this.xwins.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        this.xwins.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        this.xwins.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        this.xwins.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.ITALIC,14));
        this.xwins.setVisible(true);
        this.xwins.setOpaque(true);
        this.xwins.setText("X: " + xScore);

        this.owins.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        this.owins.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        this.owins.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        this.owins.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.ITALIC,14));
        this.owins.setVisible(true);
        this.owins.setOpaque(true);
        this.owins.setText("O: " + oScore);

        this.draws.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        this.draws.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        this.draws.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        this.draws.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.ITALIC,14));
        this.draws.setVisible(true);
        this.draws.setOpaque(true);
        this.draws.setText("D: " + drawScore);

        this.indices.put(s1,1);
        this.indices.put(s2,2);
        this.indices.put(s3,3);
        this.indices.put(s4,4);
        this.indices.put(s5,5);
        this.indices.put(s6,6);
        this.indices.put(s7,7);
        this.indices.put(s8,8);
        this.indices.put(s9,9);

        this.states.put(1,'e');
        this.states.put(2,'e');
        this.states.put(3,'e');
        this.states.put(4,'e');
        this.states.put(5,'e');
        this.states.put(6,'e');
        this.states.put(7,'e');
        this.states.put(8,'e');
        this.states.put(9,'e');

    }
    public void winCheck() {
        boolean row1 = states.get(1).equals(states.get(2)) && states.get(2).equals(states.get(3)) && !states.get(1).equals('e');
        boolean row2 = states.get(4).equals(states.get(5)) && states.get(5).equals(states.get(6)) && !states.get(4).equals('e');
        boolean row3 = states.get(7).equals(states.get(8)) && states.get(8).equals(states.get(9)) && !states.get(7).equals('e');
        boolean column1 = states.get(1).equals(states.get(4)) && states.get(4).equals(states.get(7)) && !states.get(1).equals('e');
        boolean column2 = states.get(2).equals(states.get(5)) && states.get(5).equals(states.get(8)) && !states.get(2).equals('e');
        boolean column3 = states.get(3).equals(states.get(6)) && states.get(6).equals(states.get(9)) && !states.get(3).equals('e');
        boolean diagonal1 = states.get(1).equals(states.get(5)) && states.get(5).equals(states.get(9)) && !states.get(1).equals('e');
        boolean diagonal2 = states.get(7).equals(states.get(5)) && states.get(5).equals(states.get(3)) && !states.get(7).equals('e');
        boolean full = !states.get(1).equals('e') && !states.get(2).equals('e') && !states.get(3).equals('e') && !states.get(4).equals('e') && !states.get(5).equals('e') && !states.get(6).equals('e') && !states.get(7).equals('e') && !states.get(8).equals('e') && !states.get(9).equals('e');
        boolean win = row1 || row2 || row3 || column1 || column2 || column3 ||diagonal1 || diagonal2;

        if (live) {
            if (row1) {
                if (states.get(1).equals('x')) {
                    this.xWin();
                    return;
                }
                if (states.get(1).equals('o')) {
                    this.oWin();
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (row2) {
                if (states.get(4).equals('x')) {
                    this.xWin();
                    return;
                }
                if (states.get(4).equals('o')) {
                    this.oWin();
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (row3) {
                if (states.get(7).equals('x')) {
                    this.xWin();
                    return;
                }
                if (states.get(7).equals('o')) {
                    this.oWin();
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (column1) {
                if (states.get(1).equals('x')) {
                    this.xWin();
                    return;
                }
                if (states.get(1).equals('o')) {
                    this.oWin();
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (column2) {
                if (states.get(2).equals('x')) {
                    this.xWin();
                    return;
                }
                if (states.get(2).equals('o')) {
                    this.oWin();
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (column3) {
                if (states.get(3).equals('x')) {
                    this.xWin();
                    return;
                }
                if (states.get(3).equals('o')) {
                    this.oWin();
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (diagonal1) {
                if (states.get(1).equals('x')) {
                    this.xWin();
                    return;
                }
                if (states.get(1).equals('o')) {
                    this.oWin();
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (diagonal2) {
                if (states.get(7).equals('x')) {
                    this.xWin();
                    return;
                }
                if (states.get(7).equals('o')) {
                    this.oWin();
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (full && !win) {
                drawScore++;
                this.xwins.setText("X: " + xScore);
                this.owins.setText("O: " + oScore);
                this.draws.setText("D: " + drawScore);
                live = false;
            }
        }
    }
    public void xWin() {
        oScore++;
        this.xwins.setText("X: " + xScore);
        this.owins.setText("O: " + oScore);
        this.draws.setText("D: " + drawScore);
        live = false;
    }
    public void oWin() {
        xScore++;
        this.xwins.setText("X: " + xScore);
        this.owins.setText("O: " + oScore);
        this.draws.setText("D: " + drawScore);
        live = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == newgame) {
            live = true;
            this.turn.setText("X's Turn");
        }
    }
    class Square extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
        Square() {
            centerpanel.add(this);
            this.addMouseListener(this);
            this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            this.setVisible(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            ((Graphics2D) g).setPaint(Color.RED);
            ((Graphics2D) g).setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
            if (live) {
                if (xturn) {
                    Shape x1 = new Line2D.Double(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
                    Shape x2 = new Line2D.Double(0, this.getHeight(), this.getWidth(), 0);
                    ((Graphics2D) g).draw(x1);
                    ((Graphics2D) g).draw(x2);
                } else {
                    Shape o = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, Math.min(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight()), Math.min(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight()));
                    ((Graphics2D) g).draw(o);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (live && states.get(indices.get(this)).equals('e')) {
                if (xturn) {
                    turn.setText("X's Turn");
                    states.replace(indices.get(this),'x');
                } else {
                    turn.setText("O's Turn");
                    states.replace(indices.get(this),'o');
                }
                repaint();
                winCheck();
                xturn = !xturn;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Any ideas would be appreciated"* - [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: I'd be more conscious of who is responsible for what. For example, is it really the `Square`'s responsibility to update the state of the game?  Maybe it should be delegate that another party, ie when clicked, it would notify some kind of observer/delegate that the square was clicked and then that delegate would deal with the logic of updating the state - this all falls into the concept of model-view-controller and "single responsibility principle"

Comment: `extends JFrame`, but then you create another instance of `JFrame` - the code is already confusing, this is just making it worse

Comment: The last move isn't getting printing because `live` is now `false`.  Also, the `Square` should be painting it's OWN state, not the state based on the current game.  The fact that it's x or o's turn should be irrelevant to it

Answer (score 1):

You, really, really, need to take a look at things like:

- [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)
- [Model-View-Controller](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm) - I mean, seriously, there is a LOT of information about this available on line, just do some searching
- [Single Responsibility Principle](https://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html)

The last move isn't getting painted because `live` is now `false`. Because `Square` is relying on this (and other) external state, it doesn't update.  This really is just bad design.  `Square` should be self contained and independent of anything else, then `paintComponent` would simply paint that state - it doesn't care who's go it is, does it represent it a empty cell, X or 0 - that's all it cares about.

Having said that, you should probably also take a look at:

- [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

For instance, `repaint` doesn't repaint the component immediately, this is a request to the paint manager to schedule an update for this component on the next paint pass, which won't occur (at the very least) until (in this case), the `mouseClicked` method exists.  This is why `paintComponent` is effected by the state change of `live`.

When you click "New", you need to completely re-set that state, this includes setting up who's turn it is (in this case `x`s - because this confused the  out of me and makes your code read backwards, it's "x"'s turn but you're updating the state of "o" ), reseting all the `states` back to `e` and forcing the cells to repaint...

```
if (e.getSource() == newgame) {
    live = true;
    xturn = true;
    for (int index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
        this.states.put(index + 1, 'e');
    }
    this.turn.setText("X's Turn");
    s1.repaint();
    s2.repaint();
    s3.repaint();
    s4.repaint();
    s5.repaint();
    s6.repaint();
    s7.repaint();
    s8.repaint();
    s9.repaint();
}
```

Remember where I said, learn about arrays ... this is why.

## Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TicTacToe());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TicTacToe extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
        JPanel northpanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel centerpanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel eastborder = new JPanel();
        JPanel westborder = new JPanel();
        JPanel southborder = new JPanel();
        JButton newgame = new JButton();
        JLabel turn = new JLabel();
        JLabel score = new JLabel();
        boolean xturn;
        boolean live = false;
        // Arrays, you must learn arrays
        Square s1 = new Square();
        Square s2 = new Square();
        Square s3 = new Square();
        Square s4 = new Square();
        Square s5 = new Square();
        Square s6 = new Square();
        Square s7 = new Square();
        Square s8 = new Square();
        Square s9 = new Square();
        HashMap<Square, Integer> indices = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<Integer, Character> states = new HashMap<>();
        JLabel xwins = new JLabel();
        JLabel owins = new JLabel();
        JLabel draws = new JLabel();
        int oScore = 0;
        int xScore = 0;
        int drawScore = 0;

        public TicTacToe() {
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.add(northpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            this.add(centerpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            this.add(eastborder, BorderLayout.EAST);
            this.add(westborder, BorderLayout.WEST);
            this.add(southborder, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            this.northpanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            this.northpanel.setVisible(true);
            this.northpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
            this.northpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
            this.northpanel.add(newgame);
            this.northpanel.add(turn);
            this.northpanel.add(score);

            this.centerpanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            this.centerpanel.setVisible(true);
            this.centerpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

            this.eastborder.setVisible(true);
            this.eastborder.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            this.eastborder.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1, 100));

            this.westborder.setVisible(true);
            this.westborder.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            this.westborder.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1, 100));

            this.southborder.setVisible(true);
            this.southborder.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            this.southborder.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 1));

            this.newgame.addActionListener(this);
            this.newgame.setVisible(true);
            this.newgame.setText("New Game");
            this.newgame.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 20));
            this.newgame.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            this.newgame.setFocusable(false);
            this.newgame.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            this.newgame.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            this.newgame.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

            this.turn.setVisible(true);
            this.turn.setOpaque(true);
            this.turn.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            this.turn.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            this.turn.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 20));
            this.turn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            this.turn.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

            this.score.setVisible(true);
            this.score.setOpaque(true);
            this.score.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            this.score.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            this.score.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
            this.score.add(xwins);
            this.score.add(owins);
            this.score.add(draws);

            this.xwins.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            this.xwins.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            this.xwins.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            this.xwins.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 14));
            this.xwins.setVisible(true);
            this.xwins.setOpaque(true);
            this.xwins.setText("X: " + xScore);

            this.owins.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            this.owins.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            this.owins.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            this.owins.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 14));
            this.owins.setVisible(true);
            this.owins.setOpaque(true);
            this.owins.setText("O: " + oScore);

            this.draws.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            this.draws.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            this.draws.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            this.draws.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 14));
            this.draws.setVisible(true);
            this.draws.setOpaque(true);
            this.draws.setText("D: " + drawScore);

            // Okay, this is kind of werid (to me)
            // Alot of this could be maintained by the Square itself (ie
            // I represented cell X and my value is Y)
            // Then you'd just use some kind of model and observer patterns
            // to interactor between the model and the views
            this.indices.put(s1, 1);
            this.indices.put(s2, 2);
            this.indices.put(s3, 3);
            this.indices.put(s4, 4);
            this.indices.put(s5, 5);
            this.indices.put(s6, 6);
            this.indices.put(s7, 7);
            this.indices.put(s8, 8);
            this.indices.put(s9, 9);
            // Oh, and you could probaly do this with a single ArrayList, if
            // Square was maintaining it's own state :/
            this.states.put(1, 'e');
            this.states.put(2, 'e');
            this.states.put(3, 'e');
            this.states.put(4, 'e');
            this.states.put(5, 'e');
            this.states.put(6, 'e');
            this.states.put(7, 'e');
            this.states.put(8, 'e');
            this.states.put(9, 'e');

        }

        public void winCheck() {
            // Okay, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770321/connect-4-check-for-a-win-algorithm/32771401#32771401
            // it's related to connect four, but realstically, it can be easily adapted to tic-tac-toe
            boolean row1 = states.get(1).equals(states.get(2)) && states.get(2).equals(states.get(3)) && !states.get(1).equals('e');
            boolean row2 = states.get(4).equals(states.get(5)) && states.get(5).equals(states.get(6)) && !states.get(4).equals('e');
            boolean row3 = states.get(7).equals(states.get(8)) && states.get(8).equals(states.get(9)) && !states.get(7).equals('e');
            boolean column1 = states.get(1).equals(states.get(4)) && states.get(4).equals(states.get(7)) && !states.get(1).equals('e');
            boolean column2 = states.get(2).equals(states.get(5)) && states.get(5).equals(states.get(8)) && !states.get(2).equals('e');
            boolean column3 = states.get(3).equals(states.get(6)) && states.get(6).equals(states.get(9)) && !states.get(3).equals('e');
            boolean diagonal1 = states.get(1).equals(states.get(5)) && states.get(5).equals(states.get(9)) && !states.get(1).equals('e');
            boolean diagonal2 = states.get(7).equals(states.get(5)) && states.get(5).equals(states.get(3)) && !states.get(7).equals('e');
            boolean full = !states.get(1).equals('e') && !states.get(2).equals('e') && !states.get(3).equals('e') && !states.get(4).equals('e') && !states.get(5).equals('e') && !states.get(6).equals('e') && !states.get(7).equals('e') && !states.get(8).equals('e') && !states.get(9).equals('e');
            boolean win = row1 || row2 || row3 || column1 || column2 || column3 || diagonal1 || diagonal2;

            if (live) {
                if (row1) {
                    if (states.get(1).equals('x')) {
                        this.xWin();
                        return;
                    }
                    if (states.get(1).equals('o')) {
                        this.oWin();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if (row2) {
                    if (states.get(4).equals('x')) {
                        this.xWin();
                        return;
                    }
                    if (states.get(4).equals('o')) {
                        this.oWin();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if (row3) {
                    if (states.get(7).equals('x')) {
                        this.xWin();
                        return;
                    }
                    if (states.get(7).equals('o')) {
                        this.oWin();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if (column1) {
                    if (states.get(1).equals('x')) {
                        this.xWin();
                        return;
                    }
                    if (states.get(1).equals('o')) {
                        this.oWin();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if (column2) {
                    if (states.get(2).equals('x')) {
                        this.xWin();
                        return;
                    }
                    if (states.get(2).equals('o')) {
                        this.oWin();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if (column3) {
                    if (states.get(3).equals('x')) {
                        this.xWin();
                        return;
                    }
                    if (states.get(3).equals('o')) {
                        this.oWin();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if (diagonal1) {
                    if (states.get(1).equals('x')) {
                        this.xWin();
                        return;
                    }
                    if (states.get(1).equals('o')) {
                        this.oWin();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if (diagonal2) {
                    if (states.get(7).equals('x')) {
                        this.xWin();
                        return;
                    }
                    if (states.get(7).equals('o')) {
                        this.oWin();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if (full && !win) {
                    drawScore++;
                    this.xwins.setText("X: " + xScore);
                    this.owins.setText("O: " + oScore);
                    this.draws.setText("D: " + drawScore);
                    live = false;
                }
            }
        }

        public void xWin() {
            xScore++;
            this.xwins.setText("X: " + xScore);
            this.owins.setText("O: " + oScore);
            this.draws.setText("D: " + drawScore);
            live = false;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "O wins", "Winner, winner, chicken dinner", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }

        public void oWin() {
            oScore++;
            this.xwins.setText("X: " + xScore);
            this.owins.setText("O: " + oScore);
            this.draws.setText("D: " + drawScore);
            live = false;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "X wins", "Winner, winner, chicken dinner", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == newgame) {
                live = true;
                xturn = true;
                for (int index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
                    this.states.put(index + 1, 'e');
                }
                this.turn.setText("X's Turn");
                s1.repaint();
                s2.repaint();
                s3.repaint();
                s4.repaint();
                s5.repaint();
                s6.repaint();
                s7.repaint();
                s8.repaint();
                s9.repaint();
            }
        }

        class Square extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
            Square() {
                centerpanel.add(this);
                this.addMouseListener(this);
                this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
                this.setVisible(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                ((Graphics2D) g).setPaint(Color.RED);
                ((Graphics2D) g).setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));

                if ('o' == states.get(indices.get(this))) {
                    double radius = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) / 2.0;
                    double x = (getWidth() / 2) - radius;
                    double y = (getHeight() / 2) - radius;
                    Shape o = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, radius, radius);
                    ((Graphics2D) g).draw(o);
                } else if ('x' == states.get(indices.get(this))) {
                    Shape x1 = new Line2D.Double(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
                    Shape x2 = new Line2D.Double(0, this.getHeight(), this.getWidth(), 0);
                    ((Graphics2D) g).draw(x1);
                    ((Graphics2D) g).draw(x2);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (live && states.get(indices.get(this)).equals('e')) {
                    if (xturn) {
                        turn.setText("X's Turn");
                        states.replace(indices.get(this), 'x');
                    } else {
                        turn.setText("O's Turn");
                        states.replace(indices.get(this), 'o');
                    }
                    repaint();
                    winCheck();
                    xturn = !xturn;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```