# Determining a winner on a grid of 8x8 tic tac toe

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the diagonals of a matrix that is at least 5x5; trying to loop through new columns in multiple rows. The example I have is 8x8. I can't get it to trigger the middle section as recorded "hits" in a sequence diagonally. Here is my code. This is regarding button presses that then register a persons choice, based on a player color. It loops through fine on the edges like this:

```
JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[8][8];
String red = "";
String green = "";
string blue = "";
int col = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++, col++) {
            if (buttons[row][col].getBackground() == Color.RED) {
                red = red.concat("+");
            } else if (buttons[row][col].getBackground() == Color.GREEN) {
                green = green.concat("+");
            } else if (buttons[row][col].getBackground() == Color.BLUE) {
                blue = blue.concat("+");
            } else {
                red = red.concat(",");
                green = green.concat(",");
                blue = blue.concat(",");
            }
        }
```

I am trying to solve it like this:

```
JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[8][8];
String red = "";
String green = "";
string blue = "";
int col = 0;
for (int loop = 0; loop < 5; loop++) {
        for (int row = (0 + loop); row < 8; row++, col++) {
            if (buttons[row][col].getBackground() == Color.RED) {
                red = red.concat("+");
            } else if (buttons[row][col].getBackground() == Color.GREEN) {
                green = green.concat("+");
            } else if (buttons[row][col].getBackground() == Color.BLUE) {
                blue = blue.concat("+");
            } else {
                red = red.concat(",");
                green = green.concat(",");
                blue = blue.concat(",");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi Valentine - could you point to us the specific lines in the snippet causing the problems? Also tell us more about the problems.

Comment: I would recommend separating your UI and data so that you can better abstract and model your data.  The UI should be a representation of the state of your model.  This would then allow you do things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770321/connect-4-check-for-a-win-algorithm/32771401#32771401) - while this is a connect 4 example, the core is basically the same thing you want to do

Comment: What you're currently counting is the TOTAL number of things that are red, blue or green in the entire row, column or diagonal, REGARDLESS of where they are, meaning there could be spaces in-between them. Do the four things need to be NEXT TO EACH OTHER with NO SPACES in-between them?

Comment: I've since figured using a string that has a color assignment and you use the assignment for sequences of up to 4 in a direction, do that for a scan from 8 directions, from each angle 2d.

Comment: I've updated the code to be a bit more informative of my situation.

When a diagonal is figured, in a sequence of 4 +'s, when checking for the winner; the winner fails to be declared. Only when the check is anywhere in the middle.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a picture of your interface with a win condition, a no win condition, and possibly a win condition that isn't being detected by your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

What I came up with is that I am always checking only from top to bottom and

- Only to the right
- Only to the bottom
- Bottom down diagonally
- Bottom left diagonally

So in my opinion this covers all possible wining configurations if the search is done field by field from the top.

I use 1D array to represent the gameboard and I always check if any of those checks can be performed or not, and skipping the one that.

Running example tries to randomly fill the board of given dimensions step by step and stops execution when winning condition is met (or it is a tie).

For checking winning conditions I just define the "field index progression" for the next field so I can do the `ckeck` as simple `for` loop.

```
public class TheGame {


static int side = 8;
static int fieldsCount = side * side;
static int[] fields = new int[fieldsCount];
static int toWin = 5;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //generate list of random picks
    List<Integer> fieldsToBet = IntStream.range(0, fields.length).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.shuffle(fieldsToBet);
    Iterator<Integer> it = fieldsToBet.iterator();
    Arrays.fill(fields, ' ');
    
    //place bets using list above
    char nextBet = 0;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        nextBet = nextBet == 'o' ? 'x' : 'o';
        Integer idx = it.next();
        fields[idx] = nextBet;
        char winner=(char) gameOver(idx); //check the condition, if game is done, return the winner
        if (winner > 0) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Winner is: " + nextBet);
            break;
        }
    }
    printout();
}

private static int gameOver(Integer i) {
        if (fields[i] == ' ') {
            return 0;
        }
        int column = i % side; //this can be ommited if using nested for loops
        int row = i / side;
        boolean canCheckRight = column + toWin <= side;
        boolean canCheckDown = row <= side - toWin;
        boolean canCheckLeft = column + 1 - toWin >= 0;

        boolean canCheckRightDownDiagonal = canCheckDown && canCheckRight;
        boolean canCheckLeftDownDiagonal = canCheckDown && canCheckLeft;

        boolean itsEnd =
                canCheckRight && check(i, toWin, idx -> idx += 1) || //every field to check is just "next field"
                        canCheckDown && check(i, toWin, idx -> idx += side) || // every field to check is in next row
                        canCheckRightDownDiagonal && check(i, toWin, idx -> idx += side + 1) || // next field to check is in next row skewed by 1 to the right
                        canCheckLeftDownDiagonal && check(i, toWin, idx -> idx += side - 1);// next field to check is in next row skewed by 1 to the left
        return itsEnd ? fields[i]:0;
}

private static boolean check(int idx, int iterations, Function<Integer, Integer> nextCoordinateProducer) {
    int figure = fields[idx];
    if (figure == ' ') {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < iterations; i++) {
        idx = nextCoordinateProducer.apply(idx);
        if (figure != fields[idx]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void printout() {
    for (int i = 0; i < fieldsCount; i += side) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(fields)
                .skip(i)
                .limit(side)
                .boxed()
                .map(v -> Character.valueOf((char) v.intValue()).toString())
                .collect(Collectors.joining("|")));
    }
}

}
```