# How to deal with very big Bitboards

Tags: python, c++, bitboard

I'm working on a 2-player board game (e.g. *connect 4*), with parametric board size *h*, *w*. I want to check for winning condition using *hw*-sized bitboards.

In game like chess, where board size is fixed, bitboards are usually represented with some sort of 64-bit integer. When *h* and *w* are not constant and maybe very big (let's suppose 30*30) are bitboards a good idea? If so, are the any data types in C/C++ to deal with big bitboards keeping their performances?

Since I'm currently working on python a solution in this language is appreciated too! :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: In C or in C++? They are different languages. In C++ you can use [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

Comment: What constitutes a win condition in your game?  I imagine that would have a lot to do with the solution to this issue.

Comment: @AntonSavin C++ is fine. Redings bitset notes *If the size of the bitset is not known at compile time, std::vector<bool> or boost::dynamic_bitset may be used.*

Comment: @RoddeyFrost k tiles in a row. I found Ammer's answer here really inspiring to try to implement a generic algorithm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033165/algorithm-to-check-a-connect-four-field

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this code while ago just to play around with the game concept. There is no intelligence behaviour involve. just random moves to demonstrate the game. I guess this is not important for you since you are only looking for a fast check of winning conditions. This implementation is fast since I did my best to avoid for loops and use only built-in python/numpy functions (with some tricks).

```
import numpy as np

row_size = 6
col_size = 7
symbols = {1:'A', -1:'B', 0:' '}

def was_winning_move(S, P, current_row_idx,current_col_idx):
    #****** Column Win ******
    current_col = S[:,current_col_idx]
    P_idx= np.where(current_col== P)[0]
    #if the difference between indexes are one, that means they are consecutive.
    #we need at least 4 consecutive index. So 3 Ture value
    is_idx_consecutive = sum(np.diff(P_idx)==1)>=3
    if is_idx_consecutive:
        return True

    #****** Column Win ****** 
    current_row = S[current_row_idx,:]
    P_idx= np.where(current_row== P)[0]
    is_idx_consecutive = sum(np.diff(P_idx)==1)>=3
    if is_idx_consecutive:
        return True

    #****** Diag Win ****** 
    offeset_from_diag = current_col_idx - current_row_idx
    current_diag = S.diagonal(offeset_from_diag)
    P_idx= np.where(current_diag== P)[0]
    is_idx_consecutive = sum(np.diff(P_idx)==1)>=3
    if is_idx_consecutive:
        return True
    #****** off-Diag Win ****** 
    #here 1) reverse rows, 2)find new index, 3)find offest and proceed as diag
    reversed_rows = S[::-1,:] #1
    new_row_idx = row_size - 1 - current_row_idx #2
    offeset_from_diag = current_col_idx - new_row_idx #3
    current_off_diag = reversed_rows.diagonal(offeset_from_diag)
    P_idx= np.where(current_off_diag== P)[0]
    is_idx_consecutive = sum(np.diff(P_idx)==1)>=3
    if is_idx_consecutive:
        return True
    return False

def move_at_random(S,P):
    selected_col_idx = np.random.permutation(range(col_size))[0]
    #print selected_col_idx
    #we should fill in matrix from bottom to top. So find the last filled row in col and fill the upper row
    last_filled_row = np.where(S[:,selected_col_idx] != 0)[0]
    #it is possible that there is no filled array. like the begining of the game
    #in this case we start with last row e.g row : -1
    if last_filled_row.size != 0:
        current_row_idx = last_filled_row[0] - 1
    else:
        current_row_idx = -1
    #print 'col[{0}], row[{1}]'.format(selected_col,current_row)
    S[current_row_idx, selected_col_idx] = P
    return (S,current_row_idx,selected_col_idx)

def move_still_possible(S):
    return not (S[S==0].size == 0)

def print_game_state(S):
    B = np.copy(S).astype(object)
    for n in [-1, 0, 1]:
        B[B==n] = symbols[n]
    print B

def play_game():
    #initiate game state
    game_state = np.zeros((6,7),dtype=int)
    player = 1
    mvcntr = 1
    no_winner_yet = True
    while no_winner_yet and  move_still_possible(game_state):
        #get player symbol
        name = symbols[player]

        game_state, current_row, current_col = move_at_random(game_state, player)
        #print '******',player,(current_row, current_col)
        #print current game state
        print_game_state(game_state)
        #check if the move was a winning move
        if was_winning_move(game_state,player,current_row, current_col):
            print 'player %s wins after %d moves' % (name, mvcntr)
            no_winner_yet = False

        # switch player and increase move counter
        player *= -1
        mvcntr +=  1
    if no_winner_yet:
        print 'game ended in a draw'
        player = 0
    return game_state,player,mvcntr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    S, P, mvcntr =  play_game()
```

let me know if you have any question

**UPDATE:** Explanation:

At each move, look at column, row, diagonal and secondary diagonal that goes through the current cell and find consecutive cells with the current symbol. avoid scanning the whole board.

[image]

extracting cells in each direction:

column:

```
current_col = S[:,current_col_idx]
```

row:

```
current_row = S[current_row_idx,:]
```

Diagonal:
Find the offset of the desired diagonal from the
main diagonal:

```
diag_offset = current_col_idx - current_row_idx
current_diag = S.diagonal(offset)
```

off-diagonal:

Reverse the rows of matrix:

```
S_reversed_rows = S[::-1,:]
```

Find the row index in the new matrix

```
new_row_idx = row_size - 1 - current_row_idx
current_offdiag = S.diagonal(offset)
```

[image]