# Connect 4 check Diagonal win

Tags: java, algorithm

Iam writing on a connect four game. I have implemented a check for horizontal and vertical.

Now I am stuck at the diagonal check, I am not sure how to do it. 
Here are my check functions:

```
 public boolean checkWinRows() {
    int sameDiscs;
    Player lastPlayerField = gameField[0][0].getPlayer();

    for(int i = 0; i < gameField.length; i++) {

        sameDiscs = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < gameField[i].length; j++) {

            sameDiscs = countSameDiscs(sameDiscs, gameField[i][j].getPlayer() == lastPlayerField, gameField[i][j]);
            lastPlayerField = gameField[i][j].getPlayer();

            if(sameDiscs == 4) {
                // set winner
                lastPlayerField.setWon(true);
                return true;
            }

        }
    }

    return false;
}

public boolean checkWinCols() {
    int sameDiscs;
    Player lastPlayerField = gameField[0][0].getPlayer();

    for(int j = 0; j < gameField[0].length; j++) {
        sameDiscs = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < gameField.length; i++) {

            sameDiscs = countSameDiscs(sameDiscs, gameField[i][j].getPlayer() == lastPlayerField, gameField[i][j]);
            lastPlayerField = gameField[i][j].getPlayer();

            if(sameDiscs == 4) {
                // set winner
                lastPlayerField.setWon(true);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
    private int countSameDiscs(int sameDiscs, boolean samePlayer, Field field) {
    if(field.getPlayer() != null) {
        if(samePlayer)
            sameDiscs ++;
        else
            sameDiscs = 1;
    } else
        sameDiscs = 0;
    return sameDiscs;
}
```

Now I am not sure how to do the diagonal check. I know I can go through all cols and rows, but how can I count the tokens which are diagonally placed?

Greetings

**EDIT:**

Here are my two diagonal check functions:

```
public boolean checkWinDiagonal1(int row, int column) {
    int i=0, j=0;
    int iterateCount= 4;
     int sameDiscs;
     Player lastPlayerField = gameField[0][0].getPlayer();
      for( i=row, j=column; iterateCount>0; i++, j--, iterateCount--) {
          sameDiscs = 0;
          sameDiscs = countSameDiscs(sameDiscs, gameField[i][j].getPlayer() == lastPlayerField, gameField[i][j]);
          lastPlayerField = gameField[i][j].getPlayer();

          if(sameDiscs == 4) {
              // set winner
              lastPlayerField.setWon(true);
              return true;
          }

      }
    return false;
}

public boolean checkWinDiagonal2(int row, int column) {
    int i=0, j=0;
    int iterateCount= 4;
    int sameDiscs;
    Player lastPlayerField = gameField[0][0].getPlayer();
      for( i=row, j=column; iterateCount>0; i++, j++, iterateCount--) {
          sameDiscs = 0;
          sameDiscs = countSameDiscs(sameDiscs, gameField[i][j].getPlayer() == lastPlayerField, gameField[i][j]);
          lastPlayerField = gameField[i][j].getPlayer();

          if(sameDiscs == 4) {
              // set winner
              lastPlayerField.setWon(true);
              return true;
          }
      }
   return false;
```

}

I get this error message: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: take a look at Christian Ammer's answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033165/algorithm-to-check-a-connect-four-field

Comment: I am not sure how to adpat it for my code?

Answer (score 0):

Connect 4 game is a 7*6 matrix and hence we can solve it as follows

**Matrix Entries**

00 01 02 03 04 05 06

10 11 12 13 14 15 16

20 21 22 23 24 25 26

30 31 32 33 34 35 36

40 41 42 43 44 45 46

50 51 52 53 54 55 56

Matches for connect 4 in the diagonals can happen in forward and backward diagonals.

**Forward Diagonals:**

Diagonals which are following forward slash "/" are named here as forward diagonals.

Sample matches
   03, 12, 21, 30 or 23, 32, 41, 50 or 26, 35, 44, 53 and so on

Let us come up with an array with the starting row and column entries of forward diagonals

It should be 03, 04, 05, 06, 16, 26.

In this array I have added the count, so that it will be easy to iterate and find the match

Forward Diagonals :

[ (0,3,4), (0,4,5), (0,5,6), (0,6,6), (1,6,5), (2,6,4)] 
 read as row, column and count

Iterate the forward diagonals array and invoke forwardDiagonals method

```
public boolean forwardDiagonals(int row, int column, int iterateCount){
  int i=0, j=0;
  for( i=row, j=column; iterateCount>0; i++, j--, iterateCount--) {

    // Matching logic goes here

  }
}
```

**Backward Diagonals**

Diagonals which are following backward slash "\" are named here as backward diagonals.

Sample matches
   03, 14, 25, 36 or 20, 31, 42, 53 or 11, 22, 33, 44 and so on

Let us come up with an array with the starting row and column entries of backward diagonals

It should be 20, 10, 00, 01, 02, 03.

Same approach is followed for this array and we have the iterative count, so that it will be easy to iterate and find the match

Backward Diagonals :

```
[ (2,0,4), (1,0,5), (0,0,6), (0,1,6), (0,2,5), (0,3,4)] 
read as row, column and count
```

Iterate the backward diagonals array and invoke backwardDiagonals method

```
public boolean backwardDiagonals(int row, int column, int iterateCount){
  int i=0, j=0;
  for( i=row, j=column; iterateCount>0; i++, j++, iterateCount--) {

    // Matching logic goes here

  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do so, but it doesnt work, it gives an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. How can I adapt it for my code? And what iterateCount should I choose?

Comment: I have given you the arrays with forward and backward diagonal with the starting row, starting column and the iteration count. I have highlighted the same in the answer, please have a look into that.