# if background image of a panel is equal to image in my resources

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

This is a function i wrote, but it outputs msgbox("**error**") in the **else** section.

What is happening in my code:
It's a tic tac toe program, when background image of three horizontal panels equal to imagefile in my resources then change label text.

Can anybody help me to figure out the problem?

```vb
Function win_status()
    If Panel1.Enabled = False And Panel2.Enabled = False And Panel3.Enabled = False Then
        If Panel1.BackgroundImage Is My.Resources.ticcross And Panel2.BackgroundImage Is My.Resources.ticcross And Panel3.BackgroundImage Is My.Resources.ticcross Then
            lblWinner.Text = "Player 1 Won The Game"
        Else
            MsgBox("error")
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: If you really want to compare Bitmaps references (you shouldn't need to), you have to assign resource objects to Bitmap objects and use these references for the comparison. `My.Resources` is a factory: each time you call it, it creates a new object, so it's never the same reference (in any case, you're comparing references, not the objects' content). You could build a class object to maintain a relation between a Control that uses an Image and the Image itself, possibly using a named indexer (e.g., a Dictionary) as the link between the two parts.

Comment: @Jimi can you suggest me other method to do this comparison

Comment: i need help plz

Comment: @GHOSTH4CK3R See, for example, [How to find the winner of a tic-tac-toe game of any size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198955/how-to-find-the-winner-of-a-tic-tac-toe-game-of-any-size/34478665)

Comment: I would store the STATE of each "cell" instead of relying on checking against the image itself.  A simple approach would be to put a String in the `.Tag` property of the Panel when it is claimed by a player: Nothing = Empty, "X" = Player1, "O" = Player2  Then you can check to see if the Tags are not empty, and they are all equal.  A more sophisticated approach would SEPARATE the state of the game from the User Interface itself.   This would allow you to track and play the game completely without a visual interface.  You can then change the interface and the underlying code is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed back color of pannels when it was clicked and i typed these my fuction :

it worked

`Function win_status()`

```
    If Panel4.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon And Panel5.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon And Panel6.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon Then
        lblWinner.Text = "Player 1 Wins (X)"
    ElseIf Panel4.BackColor = Color.LightCyan And Panel5.BackColor = Color.LightCyan And Panel6.BackColor = Color.LightCyan Then
        lblWinner.Text = "Player 2 Wins (O)"
    ElseIf 

    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following reference:
[Compare two images in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35153895/12666543)

In VB.NET, the code looks like:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    '...
    If CompareImg(New Bitmap(Panel1.BackgroundImage), My.Resources.ticcross) And CompareImg(New Bitmap(Panel2.BackgroundImage), My.Resources.ticcross) And CompareImg(New Bitmap(Panel3.BackgroundImage), My.Resources.ticcross) Then
        lblWinner.Text = "Player 1 Won The Game"
    Else
        MsgBox("error")
    End If
End Sub
Public Function CompareImg(ByVal bitmap1 As Bitmap, ByVal bitmap2 As Bitmap) As Boolean
    Dim lstbol As List(Of Boolean) = GetHash(bitmap1)
    Dim equalElements As Integer = lstbol.Zip(GetHash(bitmap2), Function(i, j) i = j).Count(Function(eq) eq)
    If equalElements = lstbol.Count() Then
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function
Public Function GetHash(ByVal bmpSource As Bitmap) As List(Of Boolean)
    Dim lResult As List(Of Boolean) = New List(Of Boolean)()
    Dim bmpMin As Bitmap = New Bitmap(bmpSource, New Size(16, 16))
    For j As Integer = 0 To bmpMin.Height - 1

        For i As Integer = 0 To bmpMin.Width - 1
            lResult.Add(bmpMin.GetPixel(i, j).GetBrightness() < 0.5F)
        Next
    Next
    Return lResult
End Function
```

If you want to know more about how to compare two images, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931/algorithm-to-compare-two-images).

Comment: im not comparing two images .im just checking if panel1.background image is equal to my.resources.ticcross . Thanks for your answer but its too complex. so i put my own answer how did i do easy way without comparing images