# Javascript - Tic Tac Toe - How to loop through Win Condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops, for-loop

I am writing a functioning Tic Tac Toe program and I am pretty much done. Except my win condition is too long and ugly. It looks like this.

```
function checkWin(){
  if(board[0].textContent === "X" &&
    board[1].textContent === "X" &&
    board[2].textContent === "X"
  ) { alert("Win")}
  else if (
    board[3].textContent === "X" &&
    board[4].textContent === "X" &&
    board[5].textContent === "X"
  ) { alert("Win")}
   else if (
    board[6].textContent === "X" &&
    board[7].textContent === "X" &&
    board[8].textContent === "X"
  ) { alert("Win")}

}
```

I only write a few win condition because if I write the whole thing it will be even longer. I was wondering how I can write a shorter version.
I was thinking of doing an array and looping through it but I can't figure out how.
It will be something like this.

var winConditions = [[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], [0,4,8], [6,4,2]]

but how can I use checkWin to loop through winConditions and make it equal to X and O?

Comment: This isn't an easy problem to solve. Unless you use one of the existing algorithms, it can get messy. The last time I wrote a TTT game, I checked if any of the player's tiles formed a straight line that was as long as the board. Look up existing algorithms for this problem unless you want to do it the hard way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056316/algorithm-for-determining-tic-tac-toe-game-over

Comment: And of course, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548265/testing-tic-tac-toe-win-condition/18549674#18549674

Answer (score 2):

With ES6

```js
function checkWin(player){
  // player = 'X' or 'O'

  const horizontal = [0,3,6].map(i=>{return[i,i+1,i+2]});
  const vertical = [0,1,2].map(i=>{return[i,i+3,i+6]});
  const diagonal = [[0,4,8],[2,4,6]];

  var allwins = [].concat(horizontal).concat(vertical).concat(diagonal);
  
  let res = allwins.some(indices => { 
  return board[indices[0]] == player && board[indices[1]] == player && board[indices[2]] == player})
  return res;
}
// O O O
// X X O
// X X O
var board=["X","X","O","X","X","O","O","O","O"];
console.log(checkWin("X"),"Expect: false"); // false
console.log(checkWin("O"),"Expect: true"); // true

// negative test case
var board = [];
console.log(checkWin("X"),"Expect: false"); // false

// wierd case of only 1 player
// X X X
var board = ["X","X","X"]
console.log(checkWin("X"),"Expect: true"); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing loops and sums. of course, this can be optimized :

```
var winConditions = [ /* what you defined */ ];

function winTest(board, side) {
  for(var i = 0; i < winConditions.length; i++) { 
    var sum = 0;
    var w = winConditions[i];

    for(var b = 0; b < w.length; b++) {
      if(board[w[b]].textcontent === side) {
        sum++
      }
    }

    if(sum === 3) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// then, call it :
var result = winTest(board, 'X');
```

Answer (score 0):

In the lazy version, you can join them into one string and test them with [`RegExp`](https://regex101.com/r/7OK2Ve/3):

```
function checkWin()
{
    var str = ""
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        str += board[i].textContent

    if (/(X...?)\1X|^(...)*XXX|^..X.X.X/.test(str))
        alert("Win")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the board is a flat array of strings,
then you can do this

```
function checkWinner(board) {
    let combos =  [[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], [0,4,8], [6,4,2]];

    let winner = '';
    // iterate though the combos and de-structure the set of 3 indices
    for(let [a, b, c] of combos) {
        if(board[a] && board[a] === board[b] && board[a] === board[c]) {
            return board[a]; // 'X' | 'O'
        }
    }
    return ''; // no winner
}

// ----------------- //
var board = ['X', 'X', '', 'O', 'X', 'O', '', '', 'X'];
let winner = checkWinner(board);
if(winner) {
    alert(winner + ' wins!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Oops, just noticed that this was an old question that has recently been brought back up.  I guess it still stands, though as a reasonable answer.

---

I think this does what you want, in a fairly straightforward manner.

We actually write three functions.  `anyWin` tells us if either player has a win on the board.  It calls `tictactoeWin` with `'X'` and with `'O'`, returning `true` if either of those functions did so.  `tictactoeWin` in turn is the result of calling `win` with the list of winning lines; it is a function accepting a player (`'X'` or `'O'`) and a board and returning `true` if that player wins on one of those winning lines.  `win` does the bulk of the work, finding if there is *some* line in the winning lines for which *every* cell has that player for a value.

```js
const win = (winConditions) => (player, board) =>
  winConditions .some (line => line .every (square => board [square] .textContent == player))

const tictactoeWin = win ([
  [0, 1, 2], [3, 4,5 ], [6, 7,8 ], // horizontal
  [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], // vertical
  [0, 4, 8], [6, 4, 2]             // diagonal
])

const anyWin = (board) => 
  tictactoeWin ('O', board) || tictactoeWin ('X', board)

const board = [
  {textContent: 'X'}, {textContent: ''},  {textContent: 'O'},
  {textContent: 'O'}, {textContent: 'O'}, {textContent: ''},
  {textContent: 'X'}, {textContent: 'X'}, {textContent: 'X'}
]

console .log (tictactoeWin ('O', board)) //=> false
console .log (tictactoeWin ('X', board)) //=> true
console .log (anyWin (board))            //=> true
```

If you wanted to report the winning line, it would be a fairly simple change to `win` and `anyWin`:

```js
const win = (winConditions) => (
  player, 
  board,
  line = winConditions .find (line => line .every (square => board [square] .textContent == player) )
) => ({won: !!line, ... (line ? {winner: player, line} : {})})

const tictactoeWin = win ([
  [0, 1, 2], [3, 4,5 ], [6, 7,8 ], // horizontal
  [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], // vertical
  [0, 4, 8], [6, 4, 2]             // diagonal
])

const anyWin = (board, x = tictactoeWin ('X', board)) =>
  x || tictactoeWin ('O', board)


const board = [
  {textContent: 'X'}, {textContent: ''}, {textContent: 'O'},
  {textContent: 'O'}, {textContent: 'O'}, {textContent: ''},
  {textContent: 'X'}, {textContent: 'X'}, {textContent: 'X'}
]

console .log (tictactoeWin ('O', board)) //=> false
console .log (tictactoeWin ('X', board)) //=> true
console .log (anyWin (board))            //=> true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I have one further suggestion.  You seem to be be using the DOM to store your state.  I would suggest that it would make more sense to keep a logical model of this in memory, and on a change, update the model, and redraw the UI.  That makes it much more robust.