# How can I shrink down all of these if statements?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, simplify

This part of the code is from a school assignment. I got it to work, but I feel like I can simplify it or at least make it look cleaner. However, I have not yet been able to do so. Any suggestions? (It is from a tic tac toe game)

```
if (board[0][0] == board[0][1] && board[0][1] == board[0][2] && board[0][0] != '-') {
    winner = board[0][0];
} else if (board[1][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[1][2] && board[1][0] != '-') {
    winner = board[1][0];
} else if (board[2][0] == board[2][1] && board[2][1] == board[2][2] && board[2][0] != '-') {
    winner = board[2][0];
} else if (board[0][0] == board[1][0] && board[1][0] == board[2][0] && board[0][0] != '-') {
    winner = board[0][0];
} else if (board[0][1] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][1] && board[0][1] != '-') {
    winner = board[0][1];
} else if (board[0][2] == board[1][2] && board[1][2] == board[2][2] && board[0][2] != '-') {
    winner = board[0][2];
} else if (board[2][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[0][2] && board[2][0] != '-') {
    winner = board[2][0];
} else if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2] && board[0][0] != '-') {
    winner = board[0][0];
}
```

Comment: Try using methods for each row/direction

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 if(check(board[0][0],board[0][1],board[0][2]) &&  board[0][2]!='-')
 .....


private boolean check(a,b,c){
    return a==b && b==c;
}
```

also you can see a better [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056316/algorithm-for-determining-tic-tac-toe-game-over)

Comment: sorry i misred it, let me thinkg again

Comment: No but like... This won't really help me simply the code?

Comment: see now with a fuction, just move the code in the function

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it:

```
int[][] checks = {{0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{2,0,0,1}, // horizontals
                  {0,0,1,0},{0,1,1,0},{0,2,1,0}, // verticals
                  {0,0,1,1},{2,0,-1,1}};         // diagonals
char winner = '-';
for (int[] check : checks)
    if ((winner = checkWinner(board, check[0], check[1], check[2], check[3])) != '-')
        break;
```

```
private static char checkWinner(char[][] board, int y, int x, int dy, int dx) {
    char c = board[y][x];
    return (board[y + dy][x + dx] == c && board[y + dy * 2][x + dx * 2] == c ? c : '-');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about following approach. As I can see, you have limited number of winners: `board[0][0]`, `board[1][0]`, `board[2][0]`, `board[0][1]`, `board[2][0]`. You can create separate `Predicate` for each winnger with appropriate name.

```
Predicate<char[][]> isZeroOneWinner = new Predicate<char[][]>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(char[][] board) {
        return board[0][1] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][1] && board[0][1] != '-';
    }
};
```

I think is is better that multiple `if...else`.